# extracting a particular position word from a url

Tags: javascript

I have a url string, i need to get the last word of without extension.

I need to get the **tiger** word from this
so what i am trying is
I am able to get it, is there any simple way to achieve this.

```js
let url = "https://lorem.ipsum/picsum.photos/id/tiger.png"

let word = url.split("/").reverse()[0].split(".")[0]

console.log(word)
```

Comment: what is wrong with the method you are using?

Comment: That looks like a good way to achieve it

Comment: Sure thanks @LelioFaieta @ axtck i was thinking since using multiple array methods, there could a simpler regex option

Comment: Does this answer your question? [js function to get filename from url](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/511761/js-function-to-get-filename-from-url)

Comment: *"... there could a simpler regex option"* Regex and simpler is an oxymoron.

Comment: Sure will use the same as posted thanks everyone @zer00ne