# Extracting part of element source using nightwatchjs

Tags: javascript, nightwatch.js

I'm currently using nightwatchjs to create my test scripts and have hit a stumbling block.

What I need to do it 'extract' a certain part of an element attribute, in order to use this value later on in my tests.

So, here is the element under test;

`<img class="rsTmb" src="https://parkers-images.dev.bauersecure.com/gallery-thumbnail/wp-images/20320/cut-out/79x79/lexus-ux-001.jpg`

and what I'd like to do is extract the `lexus-ux-001.jpg` part of the `src` attribute so I can use it later.

Firstly, is it possible to extract parts of an attribute using nightwatch and/or javascript, and if so any ideas how I would go about this?

Many thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is possible using the below two steps:

1. Get the href attribute value using [`getAttribute`](https://nightwatchjs.org/api/getAttribute.html) method from nightwatchjs. The example in the page already have the code to do that.
2. You can then process your URL using js methods. I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17143667/3879644) to be a simple way.