# How do I get the filename without the extension from a path in Python?

Tags: python, string, path

How do I get the filename without the extension from a path in Python?

```
"/path/to/some/file.txt"  →  "file"
```

Answer (score 1806, accepted):

#### Python 3.4+

Use [`pathlib.Path.stem`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html#pathlib.PurePath.stem)

```
>>> from pathlib import Path
>>> Path("/path/to/file.txt").stem
'file'
>>> Path("/path/to/file.tar.gz").stem
'file.tar'
```

#### Python < 3.4

Use [`os.path.splitext`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.path.html#os.path.splitext) in combination with [`os.path.basename`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.path.html#os.path.basename):

```
>>> os.path.splitext(os.path.basename("/path/to/file.txt"))[0]
'file'
>>> os.path.splitext(os.path.basename("/path/to/file.tar.gz"))[0]
'file.tar'
```

Comment: If this is a common enough operation, perhaps it should merit it's own official command? Something like os.path.filename(path_to_file) instead of os.path.splitext(os.path.basename(path_to_file))[0]

Comment: What if the filename contains multiple dots?

Comment: For anyone wondering the same as matteok, if there are multiple dots, splitext splits at the last one (so `splitext('kitty.jpg.zip')` gives `('kitty.jpg', '.zip')`).

Comment: Bears some similarity to [this SO question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8384737/python-extract-file-name-from-path-no-matter-what-the-os-path-format) as well.

Comment: @FNord sorry, not just to bump this, but it's easy, as long as you don't mean to have it standardized in the Python Stdlib: `def filename_without_ext(path_to_file): return os.path.splitext(path_to_file)[0]`

Comment: print (basename("c:\text\test\dir\ddd.tab")) show "ddd.tab"

Comment: Note that this code returns the complete file *path* (without the extension), not just the file *name*.

Comment: yeah, so you'd have to do `splitext(basename('/some/path/to/file.txt'))[0]` (which i _always_ seem to be doing)

Comment: this isn't the answer, please update this with CplLLs answer since theres no way we are overcoming 1347 votes! arg

Comment: This is not a correct answer. Use `os.path.splitext(os.path.basename(protocol))[0]` or please refer @gimel

Comment: This is not the answer to the OPs question!

Comment: apparently, the expretion `os.path.splitext("/path/to/some/file.txt.zip/?aaa=111")[0]` returns `'/path/to/some/file.txt.zip/?aaa=111'`.
meaning it only splits on the last dot if such exists after the last `/` (slash).

Comment: This a wrong answer to the question. You say it prints `/path/to/some/file` but author explicitly said they want just `file`, not `/path/to/some/file`.

Answer (score 1307):

Use [`.stem`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html#pathlib.PurePath.stem) from [`pathlib`](https://docs.python.org/library/pathlib.html) in Python 3.4+

```
from pathlib import Path

Path('/root/dir/sub/file.ext').stem
```

will return

```
'file'
```

Note that if your file has multiple extensions `.stem` will only remove the last extension. For example, `Path('file.tar.gz').stem` will return `'file.tar'`.

Comment: This is the recommended way since python 3.

Comment: Note that, like `os.path` solutions, this will only strip one extension (or `suffix`, as `pathlib` calls it). `Path('a.b.c').stem == 'a.b'`

Comment: @BallpointBen what is the optimal way of stripping multiple suffixes? Surely there must be a better way than `Path(Path('a.b.c').stem).stem`

Comment: @hoan I think repeatedly calling `.with_suffix('')` is the way to go. You'd probably want to loop until `p.suffix == ''`.

Comment: It will not work for files with complex extensions:

`pathlib.Path('backup.tar.gz').stem` -> `'backup.tar` but expected `backup`

Comment: If the file name with extension is desired, use `name` instead of `stem`.

Comment: @pymen it depends on what you define as "extension". How about `Fantastic Mr.Fox.mp4`?

Comment: @Miladiouss recommended by whom?

Comment: @DuncanMacIntyre PEP-428: "using a dedicated class allows to enable desirable behaviours by default". But of course; it depends on your task and context.

Comment: Slightly different question from OP's: How do we keep the directory information just lose the extension, i.e. to return '/root/dir/sub/file'?

Comment: @sh37211 Path(string).parent will do that. The pathlib library in general has so many common and easy to use methods for stuff like this. https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html

Comment: @Nevermore No, that doesn't work for me, because it loses the filename portion:  Path('/root/dir/sub/file.ext').parent returns '/root/dir/sub', not '/root/dir/sub/file' as I requested. Seems however that one answer to my question would be to use Path(string).parent / Path(string).stem to combine the two.

Comment: @sh37211 Oh, I completely misunderstood your original question. Very easy solution: `Path(string).with_suffix('')` should do the trick. with_suffix() changes the suffix of a Path object to whatever string is passed in, in this case we pass in an empty string to effectively remove it.

Comment: This answer should be updated with @Nevermore's solution.

Comment: @pymen How about this for handling multiple extensions https://stackoverflow.com/a/75504878/5694144

Answer (score 764):

You can make your own with:

```
>>> import os
>>> base=os.path.basename('/root/dir/sub/file.ext')
>>> base
'file.ext'
>>> os.path.splitext(base)
('file', '.ext')
>>> os.path.splitext(base)[0]
'file'
```

Important note: If there is more than one `.` in the filename, only the last one is removed. For example:

```
/root/dir/sub/file.ext.zip -> file.ext

/root/dir/sub/file.ext.tar.gz -> file.ext.tar
```

See below for other answers that address that.

Answer (score 277):

```
>>> print(os.path.splitext(os.path.basename("/path/to/file/hemanth.txt"))[0])
hemanth
```

Comment: +1 for this. 3 exact same answers, but this is the most direct one. You just could have used `\`` for showing the code, and "/somepath/hermanth.txt" as a path instance.

Comment: @hemanth.hm Note that in this statement you provided, `os.path.basename` is not necessary. `os.path.basename` should be only used to get the file name from the file path.

Answer (score 117):

In Python 3.4+ you can use the [`pathlib`](https://docs.python.org/library/pathlib.html#pathlib.PurePath.stem) solution

```
from pathlib import Path

print(Path(your_path).resolve().stem)
```

Comment: Why do you [`resolve()`](https://docs.python.org/library/pathlib.html#pathlib.Path.resolve) the path? Is it really possible to get a path to a file and not have the filename be a part of the path without that? This means that if you're give a path to symlink, you'll return the filename (without the extension) of the file the symlink points to.

Comment: One possible reason to use `resolve()` is to help deal with the multiple dots problem.  The answer below about using the index will not work if the path is './foo.tar.gz'

Answer (score 95):

https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.path.html

In python 3 pathlib "The pathlib module offers high-level path objects."
so,

```
>>> from pathlib import Path

>>> p = Path("/a/b/c.txt")
>>> p.with_suffix('')
WindowsPath('/a/b/c')
>>> p.stem
'c'
```

Comment: This is the best python 3 solution for the generic case of removing the extension from a full path. Using stem also removes the parent path. In case you are expecting a double extension (such as bla.tar.gz) then you can even use it twice: p.with_suffix('').with_suffix('').

Answer (score 42):

As noted by @IceAdor in a comment to @user2902201's solution, `rsplit` is the simplest solution robust to multiple periods (by limiting the number of splits to `maxsplit` of just 1 (from the end of the string)).

Here it is spelt out:

```
file = 'my.report.txt'
print file.rsplit('.', maxsplit=1)[0]
```

my.report

Comment: This approach fails if files without extensions are located in directories with dot(s) in the name, e.g. `./readme`.

Answer (score 32):

If you want to keep the path to the file and just remove the extension

```
>>> file = '/root/dir/sub.exten/file.data.1.2.dat'
>>> print ('.').join(file.split('.')[:-1])
/root/dir/sub.exten/file.data.1.2
```

Comment: If you want to split on the last period, use rsplit: `'/root/dir/sub.exten/file.data.1.2.dat'.rsplit('.', 1)`

Answer (score 32):

os.path.splitext() **won't** work if there are multiple dots in the extension.

For example, images.tar.gz

```
>>> import os
>>> file_path = '/home/dc/images.tar.gz'
>>> file_name = os.path.basename(file_path)
>>> print os.path.splitext(file_name)[0]
images.tar
```

You can just find the index of the first dot in the basename and then slice the basename to get just the filename without extension.

```
>>> import os
>>> file_path = '/home/dc/images.tar.gz'
>>> file_name = os.path.basename(file_path)
>>> index_of_dot = file_name.index('.')
>>> file_name_without_extension = file_name[:index_of_dot]
>>> print file_name_without_extension
images
```

Comment: index_of_dot =  file_name.index('.') This will be done after getting the basename of the file so that it wont split at .env

Comment: Important point, as a series of extensions like this is common. `.tar.gz` `.tar.bz` `.tar.7z`

Comment: Note that `'haystack'.index('needle')` throws a ValueError exception if the needle (in above case the dot, `.`) is not found in haystack. Files without any extension exist too.

Comment: to solve that problem, use a try-catch, or use `str.find()` and check for -1. if there's no dot, then just return `file_name`

Answer (score 27):

### Answers using Pathlib for Several Scenarios

Using Pathlib, it is trivial to get the filename when there is just one extension (or none), but it can be awkward to handle the general case of multiple extensions.

#### Zero or One extension

```py
from pathlib import Path

pth = Path('./thefile.tar')

fn = pth.stem

print(fn)      # thefile


# Explanation:
# the `stem` attribute returns only the base filename, stripping
# any leading path if present, and strips the extension after
# the last `.`, if present.


# Further tests

eg_paths = ['thefile',
            'thefile.tar',
            './thefile',
            './thefile.tar',
            '../../thefile.tar',
            '.././thefile.tar',
            'rel/pa.th/to/thefile',
            '/abs/path/to/thefile.tar']

for p in eg_paths:
    print(Path(p).stem)  # prints thefile every time
```

#### Two or fewer extensions

```py
from pathlib import Path

pth = Path('./thefile.tar.gz')

fn = pth.with_suffix('').stem

print(fn)      # thefile


# Explanation:
# Using the `.with_suffix('')` trick returns a Path object after
# stripping one extension, and then we can simply use `.stem`.


# Further tests

eg_paths += ['./thefile.tar.gz',
             '/abs/pa.th/to/thefile.tar.gz']

for p in eg_paths:
    print(Path(p).with_suffix('').stem)  # prints thefile every time
```

#### Any number of extensions (0, 1, or more)

```py
from pathlib import Path

pth = Path('./thefile.tar.gz.bz.7zip')

fn = pth.name
if len(pth.suffixes) > 0:
    s = pth.suffixes[0]
    fn = fn.rsplit(s)[0]

# or, equivalently

fn = pth.name
for s in pth.suffixes:
    fn = fn.rsplit(s)[0]
    break

# or simply run the full loop

fn = pth.name
for _ in pth.suffixes:
    fn = fn.rsplit('.')[0]

# In any case:

print(fn)     # thefile


# Explanation
#
# pth.name     -> 'thefile.tar.gz.bz.7zip'
# pth.suffixes -> ['.tar', '.gz', '.bz', '.7zip']
#
# If there may be more than two extensions, we can test for
# that case with an if statement, or simply attempt the loop
# and break after rsplitting on the first extension instance.
# Alternatively, we may even run the full loop and strip one 
# extension with every pass.


# Further tests

eg_paths += ['./thefile.tar.gz.bz.7zip',
             '/abs/pa.th/to/thefile.tar.gz.bz.7zip']

for p in eg_paths:
    pth = Path(p)
    fn = pth.name
    for s in pth.suffixes:
        fn = fn.rsplit(s)[0]
        break

    print(fn)  # prints thefile every time
```

##### *Special case in which the first extension is known*

For instance, if the extension could be `.tar`, `.tar.gz`, `.tar.gz.bz`, etc; you can simply `rsplit` the known extension and take the first element:

```py
pth = Path('foo/bar/baz.baz/thefile.tar.gz')

fn = pth.name.rsplit('.tar')[0]

print(fn)      # thefile
```

Answer (score 26):

```
import os
filename, file_extension =os.path.splitext(os.path.basename('/d1/d2/example.cs'))
```

- filename is 'example'
- file_extension is '.cs'

'

Comment: this actually answers the OP's question

Answer (score 21):

> But even when I import os, I am not able to call it path.basename. Is it possible to call it as directly as basename?

`import os`, and then use `os.path.basename`

`import`ing `os` doesn't mean you can use `os.foo` without referring to `os`.

Comment: though if you wanted to call foo directly you could use `from os import foo`.

Comment: you have a very non-standard version of the `os` module if it has a member called `foo`.

Comment: It's a placeholder name. (e.g. consider `path`, or `walk`).

Answer (score 21):

Thought I would throw in a variation to the use of the [os.path.splitext](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.path.html#os.path.splitext) without the need to use array indexing.

The function always returns a `(root, ext)` pair so it is safe to use:

`root, ext = os.path.splitext(path)`

Example:

```
>>> import os
>>> path = 'my_text_file.txt'
>>> root, ext = os.path.splitext(path)
>>> root
'my_text_file'
>>> ext
'.txt'
```

Answer (score 14):

The other methods don't remove multiple extensions. Some also have problems with filenames that don't have extensions. This snippet deals with both instances and works in both Python 2 and 3. It grabs the basename from the path, splits the value on dots, and returns the first one which is the initial part of the filename.

```
import os

def get_filename_without_extension(file_path):
    file_basename = os.path.basename(file_path)
    filename_without_extension = file_basename.split('.')[0]
    return filename_without_extension
```

Here's a set of examples to run:

```
example_paths = [
    "FileName", 
    "./FileName",
    "../../FileName",
    "FileName.txt", 
    "./FileName.txt.zip.asc",
    "/path/to/some/FileName",
    "/path/to/some/FileName.txt",
    "/path/to/some/FileName.txt.zip.asc"
]

for example_path in example_paths:
    print(get_filename_without_extension(example_path))
```

In every case, the value printed is:

```
FileName
```

Comment: Except for the added value of handling multiple dots, this method is way more fast than `Path('/path/to/file.txt').stem`. (1,23μs vs 8.39μs)

Comment: This doesn't work for filename nvdcve-1.1-2002.json.zip

Comment: I split it on fileBasename.split('.json')[0] and it worked

Answer (score 7):

A multiple extension aware procedure. Works for `str` and `unicode` paths. Works in Python 2 and 3.

```
import os

def file_base_name(file_name):
    if '.' in file_name:
        separator_index = file_name.index('.')
        base_name = file_name[:separator_index]
        return base_name
    else:
        return file_name

def path_base_name(path):
    file_name = os.path.basename(path)
    return file_base_name(file_name)
```

Behavior:

```
>>> path_base_name('file')
'file'
>>> path_base_name(u'file')
u'file'
>>> path_base_name('file.txt')
'file'
>>> path_base_name(u'file.txt')
u'file'
>>> path_base_name('file.tar.gz')
'file'
>>> path_base_name('file.a.b.c.d.e.f.g')
'file'
>>> path_base_name('relative/path/file.ext')
'file'
>>> path_base_name('/absolute/path/file.ext')
'file'
>>> path_base_name('Relative\\Windows\\Path\\file.txt')
'file'
>>> path_base_name('C:\\Absolute\\Windows\\Path\\file.txt')
'file'
>>> path_base_name('/path with spaces/file.ext')
'file'
>>> path_base_name('C:\\Windows Path With Spaces\\file.txt')
'file'
>>> path_base_name('some/path/file name with spaces.tar.gz.zip.rar.7z')
'file name with spaces'
```

Answer (score 6):

```
import os
path = "a/b/c/abc.txt"
print os.path.splitext(os.path.basename(path))[0]
```

Answer (score 6):

`import os`

```
filename = C:\\Users\\Public\\Videos\\Sample Videos\\wildlife.wmv
```

This returns the `filename` without the `extension`(C:\Users\Public\Videos\Sample Videos\wildlife)

```
temp = os.path.splitext(filename)[0]
```

Now you can get just the `filename` from the temp with

```
os.path.basename(temp)   #this returns just the filename (wildlife)
```

Answer (score 6):

Very very very simpely no other modules !!!

```
import os
p = r"C:\Users\bilal\Documents\face Recognition python\imgs\northon.jpg"

# Get the filename only from the initial file path.
filename = os.path.basename(p)

# Use splitext() to get filename and extension separately.
(file, ext) = os.path.splitext(filename)

# Print outcome.
print("Filename without extension =", file)
print("Extension =", ext)
```

Answer (score 4):

On Windows system I used drivername prefix as well, like:

```
>>> s = 'c:\\temp\\akarmi.txt'
>>> print(os.path.splitext(s)[0])
c:\temp\akarmi
```

So because I do not need drive letter or directory name, I use:

```
>>> print(os.path.splitext(os.path.basename(s))[0])
akarmi
```

Answer (score 4):

Using `pathlib.Path.stem` is the right way to go, but here is an ugly solution that is way more efficient than the pathlib based approach.

You have a filepath whose fields are separated by a forward slash `/`, slashes cannot be present in filenames, so you split the filepath by `/`, the last field is the filename.

The extension is always the last element of the list created by splitting the filename by dot `.`, so if you reverse the filename and split by dot once, the reverse of the second element is the file name without extension.

```py
name = path.split('/')[-1][::-1].split('.', 1)[1][::-1]
```

Performance:

```
Python 3.9.10 (tags/v3.9.10:f2f3f53, Jan 17 2022, 15:14:21) [MSC v.1929 64 bit (AMD64)]
Type 'copyright', 'credits' or 'license' for more information
IPython 7.28.0 -- An enhanced Interactive Python. Type '?' for help.

In [1]: from pathlib import Path

In [2]: file = 'D:/ffmpeg/ffmpeg.exe'

In [3]: Path(file).stem
Out[3]: 'ffmpeg'

In [4]: file.split('/')[-1][::-1].split('.', 1)[1][::-1]
Out[4]: 'ffmpeg'

In [5]: %timeit Path(file).stem
6.15 µs ± 433 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100000 loops each)

In [6]: %timeit file.split('/')[-1][::-1].split('.', 1)[1][::-1]
671 ns ± 37.8 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000000 loops each)

In [7]:
```

---

### Update

This answer somehow got downvoted.

Anyway I just found a better solution.

I didn't know there is a `str.rsplit` function when I first posted the answer. Using it I don't need to do two reverses.

Performance:

```
In [11]: file = 'D:/ffmpeg/ffmpeg.exe'

In [12]: file.split('/')[-1][::-1].split('.', 1)[1][::-1]
Out[12]: 'ffmpeg'

In [13]: file.split('/')[-1].rsplit('.', 1)[0]
Out[13]: 'ffmpeg'

In [14]: %timeit file.split('/')[-1].rsplit('.', 1)[0]
359 ns ± 4.59 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1,000,000 loops each)

In [15]: %timeit file.split('/')[-1][::-1].split('.', 1)[1][::-1]
556 ns ± 3.9 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1,000,000 loops each)
```

Answer (score 2):

Improving upon @spinup answer:

```
fn = pth.name
for s in pth.suffixes:
    fn = fn.rsplit(s)[0]
    break
    
print(fn)      # thefile
```

This works for filenames without extension also

Answer (score 2):

I've read the answers, and I notice that there are many good solutions.
So, for those who are looking to get either (name or extension), here goes another solution, using the [os module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html), both methods support files with multiple extensions.

```
import os

def get_file_name(path):
    if not os.path.isdir(path):
        return os.path.splitext(os.path.basename(path))[0].split(".")[0]


def get_file_extension(path):
    extensions = []
    copy_path = path
    while True:
        copy_path, result = os.path.splitext(copy_path)
        if result != '':
            extensions.append(result)
        else:
            break
    extensions.reverse()
    return "".join(extensions)
```

Note: this solution on windows does not support file names with the "\" character

Answer (score 1):

We could do some simple `split` / `pop` magic as seen here (https://stackoverflow.com/a/424006/1250044), to extract the filename (respecting the windows and POSIX differences).

```
def getFileNameWithoutExtension(path):
  return path.split('\\').pop().split('/').pop().rsplit('.', 1)[0]

getFileNameWithoutExtension('/path/to/file-0.0.1.ext')
# => file-0.0.1

getFileNameWithoutExtension('\\path\\to\\file-0.0.1.ext')
# => file-0.0.1
```

Comment: os.path.splitext()[0] does the same thing.

Comment: @CharlesPlager *os.path.splitext() won't work if there are multiple dots in the extension.* http://stackoverflow.com/a/37760212/1250044

Comment: It works for me:

In [72]: os.path.splitext('one.two.three.ext')
Out[72]: ('one.two.three', '.ext')

Answer (score 1):

For convenience, a simple function wrapping the two methods from [`os.path`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.path.html) :

```
def filename(path):
  """Return file name without extension from path.

  See https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.path.html
  """
  import os.path
  b = os.path.split(path)[1]  # path, *filename*
  f = os.path.splitext(b)[0]  # *file*, ext
  #print(path, b, f)
  return f
```

Tested with Python 3.5.

Answer (score 1):

```
import os
list = []
def getFileName( path ):
for file in os.listdir(path):
    #print file
    try:
        base=os.path.basename(file)
        splitbase=os.path.splitext(base)
        ext = os.path.splitext(base)[1]
        if(ext):
            list.append(base)
        else:
            newpath = path+"/"+file
            #print path
            getFileName(newpath)
    except:
        pass
return list

getFileName("/home/weexcel-java3/Desktop/backup")
print list
```

Answer (score 1):

the easiest way to resolve this is to

```
import ntpath 
print('Base name is ',ntpath.basename('/path/to/the/file/'))
```

this saves you time and computation cost.

Answer (score 1):

I didn't look very hard but I didn't see anyone who used regex for this problem.

I interpreted the question as "given a path, return the basename without the extension."

e.g.

`"path/to/file.json"` => `"file"`

`"path/to/my.file.json"` => `"my.file"`

In Python 2.7, where we still live without `pathlib`...

```
def get_file_name_prefix(file_path):
    basename = os.path.basename(file_path)

    file_name_prefix_match = re.compile(r"^(?P<file_name_pre fix>.*)\..*$").match(basename)

    if file_name_prefix_match is None:
        return file_name
    else:
        return file_name_prefix_match.group("file_name_prefix")
```

```
get_file_name_prefix("path/to/file.json")
>> file

get_file_name_prefix("path/to/my.file.json")
>> my.file

get_file_name_prefix("path/to/no_extension")
>> no_extension
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you're already using `pathlib` and Python 3.9 or newer, here's a simple one-line approach that removes all extensions.

```py
>>> from pathlib import Path
>>> pth = Path("/path/to.some/file.foo.bar.txt")
>>> pth.name.removesuffix("".join(pth.suffixes))
'file'
```

Answer (score 0):

`>>>print(os.path.splitext(os.path.basename("/path/to/file/varun.txt"))[0])                 varun`

Here `/path/to/file/varun.txt` is the path to file and the output is `varun`

Answer (score 0):

A quick function to split all extensions of a path using `pathlib.Path` and string manipulation:

```py
def split_extensions(path: str | Path) -> tuple[str, str]:
    ext = "".join(Path(path).suffixes)
    return str(path).rstrip(ext), ext

# Usage
# >>> split_extensions("./data.tar") => ("./data", ".tar")
# >>> split_extensions("./data.tar.gz") => ("./data", ".tar.gz")
```

Edit:

Thank you @nick-k9 for the reminder:

> rstrip() takes "a string specifying the set of characters to be removed. You need to be using removesuffix()

`removesuffix()` is available from python >= 3.9

```py
def split_extensions(path: str | Path) -> tuple[str, str]:
    ext = "".join(Path(path).suffixes)
    return str(path).removesuffix(ext), ext

# Usage
# >>> split_extensions("./data.tar") => ("./data", ".tar")
# >>> split_extensions("./data.tar.gz") => ("./data", ".tar.gz")
```

Comment: Please note: `rstrip()` takes "a string specifying the set of characters to be removed." You need to be using `removesuffix()`.

Comment: Thanks for taking the comment on board. However, the original solution is actually dangerous, and I think you should use `re.sub` or another alternative before 3.9. The Usage example will not actually work as described. E.g. `split_extensions("./data.tar") => ("./d", ".tar")`

Answer (score -2):

```py
# use pathlib. the below works with compound filetypes and normal ones
source_file = 'spaces.tar.gz.zip.rar.7z'
source_path = pathlib.Path(source_file)
source_path.name.replace(''.join(source_path.suffixes), '')
>>> 'spaces'
```

despite the many working implementations described above I added this ^ as it uses pathlib only and works for compound filetypes and normal ones

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: I need from `"/path/to/some/file.txt"` to get the `/path/to/some/`  in a string. How can I achieve that?