# Get Filename Without Extension in Python

Tags: python, regex

If I have a filename like one of these:

```
1.1.1.1.1.jpg

1.1.jpg

1.jpg
```

How could I get only the filename, without the extension? Would a regex be appropriate?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to get the filename without the extension from a path in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/678236/how-to-get-the-filename-without-the-extension-from-a-path-in-python)

Answer (score 224, accepted):

In most cases, you shouldn't use a regex for that.

```
os.path.splitext(filename)[0]
```

This will also handle a filename like `.bashrc` correctly by keeping the whole name.

Comment: Does not work properly with "git-1.7.8.tar.gz", where it only removes the ".gz". I use `basename[:-len(".tar.gz")]` for this.

Comment: @blueyed: "Does not work properly" is a matter of perspective. The file *is* a gzip file, who's base name is `git-1.7.8.tar`. There is no way to correctly guess how many dots the caller wants to strip off, so `splitext()` only strips the last one. If you want to handle edge-cases like `.tar.gz`, you'll have to do it by hand. Obviously, you can't strip all the dots, since you'll end up with `git-1`.

Answer (score 27):

```
>>> import os
>>> os.path.splitext("1.1.1.1.1.jpg")
('1.1.1.1.1', '.jpg')
```

Answer (score 17):

You can use [stem](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html#pathlib.PurePath.stem) method to get file name.

Here is an example:

```
from pathlib import Path

p = Path(r"\\some_directory\subdirectory\my_file.txt")
print(p.stem)
# my_file
```

Answer (score 10):

If I had to do this with a regex, I'd do it like this:

```
s = re.sub(r'\.jpg$', '', s)
```

Answer (score 6):

No need for regex. `os.path.splitext` is your friend:

```
os.path.splitext('1.1.1.jpg')
>>> ('1.1.1', '.jpg')
```

Answer (score 0):

One can also use the string slicing.

```
>>> "1.1.1.1.1.jpg"[:-len(".jpg")]
'1.1.1.1.1'
```