# How to get rid of extensions from file basename using python

Tags: python, regex

I have got the complete path of files in a list like this:

```
a = ['home/robert/Documents/Workspace/datafile.xlsx', 'home/robert/Documents/Workspace/datafile2.xls', 'home/robert/Documents/Workspace/datafile3.xlsx']
```

what I want is to get just the file NAMES without their extensions, like:

```
b = ['datafile', 'datafile2', 'datafile3']
```

What I have tried is:

```
xfn = re.compile(r'(\.xls)+')
for name in a:
    fp, fb = os.path.split(fp)
    ofn = xfn.sub('', name)
    b.append(ofn)
```

But it results in:

```
b = ['datafilex', 'datafile2', 'datafile3x']
```

Comment: use `str.replace()` for this. it is much, **much** faster

Comment: Do you _have_ to use regexes at all? `os.path.splitext` removes the extension...

Answer (score 27, accepted):

1. The regex you've used is wrong. `(\.xls)+` matches strings of the form `.xls`, `.xls.xls`, etc. This is why there is a remaining `x` in the `.xlsx` items. What you want is `\.xls.*`, i.e. a `.xls` followed by zero or more of any characters.
2. You don't really need to use regex. There are specialized methods in [os.path](http://docs.python.org/3/library/os.path.html) that deals with this: [basename](https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.path.html#os.path.basename) and [splitext](https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.path.html#os.path.splitext).

   ```
   >>> import os.path
   >>> os.path.basename('home/robert/Documents/Workspace/datafile.xlsx')
   'datafile.xlsx'
   >>> os.path.splitext(os.path.basename('home/robert/Documents/Workspace/datafile.xlsx'))[0]
   'datafile'
   ```

   so, assuming you don't really care about the `.xls`/`.xlsx` suffix, your code can be as simple as:

   ```
   >>> a = ['home/robert/Documents/Workspace/datafile.xlsx', 'home/robert/Documents/Workspace/datafile2.xls', 'home/robert/Documents/Workspace/datafile3.xlsx']
   >>> [os.path.splitext(os.path.basename(fn))[0] for fn in a]
   ['datafile', 'datafile2', 'datafile3']
   ```

   (also note the [list comprehension](http://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions).)

Comment: +1 for both correcting OP's incorrect approach and for providing a better solution to the problem

Answer (score 4):

Oneliner:

```
>>> filename = 'file.ext'
>>> '.'.join(filename.split('.')[:-1]) if '.' in filename else filename
'file'
```

Answer (score 1):

This is a repeat of:
[How to get the filename without the extension from a path in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/678236/how-to-get-the-filename-without-the-extension-from-a-path-in-python/51475388#51475388)

https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.path.html

In python 3 pathlib "The pathlib module offers high-level path objects." so,

```
>>> from pathlib import Path
>>> p = Path("/a/b/c.txt")
>>> print(p.with_suffix(''))
\a\b\c
>>> print(p.stem)
c
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not just use the `split` method?

```
def get_filename(path):
    """ Gets a filename (without extension) from a provided path """

    filename = path.split('/')[-1].split('.')[0]
    return filename


>>> path = '/home/robert/Documents/Workspace/datafile.xlsx'
>>> filename = get_filename(path)
>>> filename
'datafile'
```

Comment: `get_filename('/path/to/some/file.tar.bz2') == 'file'` - should be `file.tar`