# How to save as a file but get its name at the same time?

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter

I am currently using `asksaveasfile` to save the file, and it is working fine. The only issue I am having is that I cant get the new file name. I know `asksaveasfilename` exists but if I use them both together they will pop up two windows which I dont want to happen. If I try printing the output of `asksaveasfile` i get the following:

```
<_io.TextIOWrapper name='/home/work/newfile.txt' mode='w' encoding='UTF-8'>.
```

Is there a way I can just get the file name out of this?

Comment: just use `asksaveasfilename` then open the file yourself, or use the `.name` attribute of the result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use the `.name` attribute of the result of `asksaveasfile`:

```
import tkinter
file = tkinter.filedialog.asksaveasfile()
name = file.name
```

Or you can use `asksaveasfilename` then open the file yourself:

```
name = tkinter.filedialog.asksaveasfilename()
file = open(name,'w')
```

This way you could also use a `with` statement to ensure the file is closed properly which would be a good idea anyway:

```
name = tkinter.filedialog.asksaveasfilename()
with open(name,'w') as f:
    NotImplemented #do stuff with the file
```

Comment: This worked,  and I used the basename() function to get the filename seperate. But I keep getting my extension in the file name too. For example I get "file.txt" but is there a way I can just get "file"?

Comment: either [python how to remove file extension on string](https://www.google.com/webhp?#q=python+how+to+remove+file+extension+on+string) or [How to get the filename without the extension from a path in Python?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/678236/how-to-get-the-filename-without-the-extension-from-a-path-in-python)

Comment: Yes ... I believe there is an os.path function to separate an extension from the rest, and it is easy to do by finding the last '.'.

Comment: @TerryJanReedy, yes it is called `splitext` and it is posted in the question I linked to.