# What is the best way to select the base name portion of the path excluding the extension in Python?

Tags: python, regex, path

I would like to select the base name portion of a file path excluding the file extension.

For example, if the path is something like the following:
**/experimental/users/nerd/wavfiles/wavfile0722.wav**
Then, I would like to select "**wavefile0722**" portion of the above path.

I have been using the following statement in Python for this purpose.

```
basename_wo_ext = re.sub('\.[^\.]*', '' , os.path.basename(file_path))
```

But I wonder whether it is a good approach or not, and if not, what would be the best way for this case.

Any suggestions are welcomed. Thank you!

Comment: [`os.path.splitext`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.path.html#os.path.splitext)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get the filename without the extension from a path in Python?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/678236/how-to-get-the-filename-without-the-extension-from-a-path-in-python)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`os.path` also includes the [`splitext`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.path.html#os.path.splitext) function for splitting the extension off of a path:

```
basename_wo_ext, possible_ext = os.path.splitext(os.path.basename(file_path))
```

Answer (score 2):

Instead of using regular expressions, you can use the power of Python's [`os.path` module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.path.html) - combine [`os.path.basename()`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/678236/how-to-get-the-filename-without-the-extension-from-a-path-in-python) and [`os.path.splitext()`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8384737/python-extract-file-name-from-path-no-matter-what-the-os-path-format):

```
In [1]: import os

In [2]: filename = "/experimental/users/nerd/wavfiles/wavfile0722.wav"

In [3]: os.path.splitext(os.path.basename(filename))[0]
Out[3]: 'wavfile0722'
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use [os.path.splitext](https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.path.html?highlight=splitext#os.path.splitext) instead of a regex.
It returns a 2 elements tuple containing the name and the extension