# How to create a file list of my files included in the same folder?

Tags: python, numpy

I have a folder which contains numpy files. I need to create a numpy list where I will put all my numpy file names. For that, I use this code:

```
import os

a = open('C:\\Users\\user\\My_Test_Traces\\Traces.list_npy', "w")
for path, subdirs, files in os.walk(r'C:\\Users\\user\\CPA_test_1000_Tests\\test'):
   for filename in files:
      f = os.path.join(path, filename)
      a.write(str(f) + os.linesep)
```

As a result, it gives me a list of my files and their paths like this:

```
   C:\\Users\\user\\My_Test_Traces\\ Trace1_Pltx1

   C:\\Users\\user\\My_Test_Traces\\ Trace2_Pltx2

   C:\\Users\\user\\My_Test_Traces\\ Trace3_Pltx3

   C:\\Users\\user\\My_Test_Traces\\ Trace4_Pltx4
```

however , I need only the files name,  I don't need any spaces between lines:

```
   Trace1_Pltx1
   Trace2_Pltx2
   Trace3_Pltx3
   Trace4_Pltx4
```

Comment: then why are you joining with the `path`? The `filename` must be what you want to have.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe this is better:

```
import os

folder = 'C:\\Users\\user\\CPA_test_1000_Tests\\test'

with open('C:\\Users\\user\\My_Test_Traces\\Traces.list_npy', 'w') as fp:
    fp.write(os.linesep.join(os.listdir(folder)))
```

Comment: what about the spaces between lines please, how to delete it?

Comment: I didn't get any space on my environment. Can you close the file Traces.list_npy and open again?

Comment: I have my spaces in all between each line

Comment: I use winPython version 3.6, it may be differs between versions of python.

Answer (score 0):

There is a function tyhat is doing exactly what you need, you should try this:

```
os.path.basename(path)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use,

```
from os.path import basename
print basename('path/file.txt')
```

If you don't want extension, refer the [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/678236/how-to-get-the-filename-without-the-extension-from-a-path-in-python)

Comment: it gives me an empty list, I need the name of my files in the list without the path