# How to remove space lines between my numpy list's file?

Tags: python, numpy

[How to create a file list of my files included in the same folder?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42901619/how-to-create-a-file-list-of-my-files-included-in-the-same-folder/42901967?noredirect=1#comment72906712_42901967) I have posted in this question that I need to put all mye file names from the same folder in one numpy file.

```
import os
folder = 'C:\\Users\\user\\CPA_test_1000_Tests\\test'
with open('C:\\Users\\user\\My_Test_Traces\\Traces.list_npy', 'w') as fp:
    fp.write(os.linesep.join(os.listdir(folder)))
```

I use this code and it works, but my still with space line between names of files, I mean that the result that I have looks like this:

```
   Trace1_Pltx1

   Trace2_Pltx2

   Trace3_Pltx3

   Trace4_Pltx4
```

However the result that I must I have, must look like this:

```
   Trace1_Pltx1
   Trace2_Pltx2
   Trace3_Pltx3
   Trace4_Pltx4
```

I don't know really what is the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at [os.linesep()](https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.html#os.linesep) method that you're calling...

As stated in the docs:

> Do not use os.linesep as a line terminator when writing files opened
>   in text mode (the default); use a single '\n' instead, on all
>   platforms.

So, instead of:

```
fp.write(os.linesep.join(os.listdir(folder)))
```

try:

```
fp.write('\n'.join(os.listdir(folder)))
```

Or you can even use

```
with open('C:\\Users\\user\\My_Test_Traces\\Traces.list_npy', 'w') as fp:
    for f in os.listdir(folder):
        fp.write(f + "\n")
```