# How to put the name of file list in order from the same folder in the same numpy file?

Tags: python, numpy

[How to create a file list of my files included in the same folder?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42901619/how-to-create-a-file-list-of-my-files-included-in-the-same-folder/42901967?noredirect=1#comment72906712_42901967)
In this  question, I have asked about how to put all my file names from the same folder in one numpy file.

```
import os
path_For_Numpy_Files = 'C:\\Users\\user\\My_Test_Traces\\1000_Traces_npy'
with open('C:\\Users\\user\\My_Test_Traces\\Traces.list_npy', 'w') as fp:
    fp.write('\n'.join(os.listdir(path_For_Numpy_Files)))
```

I have 10000 numpy files in my folder, so the result is:

```
   Tracenumber=01_Pltx1
   Tracenumber=02_Pltx2
   Tracenumber=03_Pltx3
   Tracenumber=04_Pltx4
   Tracenumber=05_Pltx5
   Tracenumber=06_Pltx6
   Tracenumber=07_Pltx7
   Tracenumber=08_Pltx8
   Tracenumber=09_Pltx9
   Tracenumber=10_Pltx10
   Tracenumber=1000_Pltx1000
   Tracenumber=100_Pltx100
   Tracenumber=101_Pltx101
```

The order is very important to analyse my result, how to keep thqt order when creating the list please? I mean that I need my results like this:

```
   Tracenumber=01_Pltx1
   Tracenumber=02_Pltx2
   Tracenumber=03_Pltx3
   Tracenumber=04_Pltx4
   Tracenumber=05_Pltx5
   Tracenumber=06_Pltx6
   Tracenumber=07_Pltx7
   Tracenumber=08_Pltx8
   Tracenumber=09_Pltx9
   Tracenumber=10_Pltx10
   Tracenumber=11_Pltx11
   Tracenumber=12_Pltx12
   Tracenumber=13_Pltx13
```

I try to iterate it by using:

```
import os
path_For_Numpy_Files = 'C:\\Users\\user\\My_Test_Traces\\1000_Traces_npy'
with open('C:\\Users\\user\\My_Test_Traces\\Traces.list_npy', 'w') as fp:
    list_files=os.listdir(path_For_Numpy_Files)
    list_files_In_Order=sorted(list_files, key=lambda x:(int(re.sub('D:\tt','',x)),x))
    fp.write('\n'.join(sorted(os.listdir(list_files_In_Order))))
```

It gives me this error:

```
invalid literal for int() with base 10: ' Tracenumber=01_Pltx1'
```

How to solve this problem please?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Numeric Sort in Python](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3426108/numeric-sort-in-python)

Comment: @Bemmu, Thank you but it isn't the same case.

Comment: If you first sort os.listdir results numerically, would that not be your solution?

Comment: If not, another thing you can try is to make a custom sort function that extracts the final number part from the filenames and sorts based on that.

Comment: @Bemmu, Could you please give me more explanation for your idea?

Comment: In your attempt, list_files.sort() sorts the list in-place, it does not return a new sorted list. Also to do the numeric sort, use list_files.sort(key=int)

Comment: @Bemmu, it gives me this error: invalid literal for int() with base 10:

Comment: Remove leading zeroes from the number. If a number starts with a zero, it is assumed to be octal instead of base 10.

Comment: I have the same error.

Answer (score 1):

I edit the solution, It may work now:
You will sort your files based on time.

```
import os
path_For_Numpy_Files = 'C:\\Users\\user\\My_Test_Traces\\1000_Traces_npy'
path_List_File='C:\\Users\\user\\My_Test_Traces\\Traces.list_npy'
with open(path_List_File, 'w') as fp:
    os.chdir(path_For_Numpy_Files)
    list_files=os.listdir(os.getcwd())
    fp.write('\n'.join(sorted((list_files),key=os.path.getmtime)))
```

Comment: it gives me the same results. The name of files are not ordered.