# Save files into different format using original filenames

Tags: operating-system, glob

After reading .csv files in a directory, I want to save each of them into .html files using their original file names. But, my code below brings along the extension (.csv) from the original filenames.

For example,
Original files: File1.csv, File2.csv
Result files: File1.csv.html, File2.csv.html

I want to remove ".csv" from the new file names.

```
import pandas as pd
import glob, os

os.chdir(r"C:\Users\.....\...")
for counter, file in enumerate(glob.glob("*.csv")):
    df = pd.read_csv(file, skipinitialspace=False, sep =',', engine='python')                           
    df.to_file(os.path.basename(file) + ".html")
```

The code below removed ".csv" but also ".html"

```
    df.to_file(os.path.basename(file + ".html").split('.')[0])
```

My **expectation** is:

File1.html, File2.html

**EDIT:**
Another post [[How to get the filename without the extension from a path in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/678236/how-to-get-the-filename-without-the-extension-from-a-path-in-python]) suggested how to list existing files without extensions. My issue, however, is to read existing files in a directory and save them using their original file names (excluding original extension) with new extension.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get the filename without the extension from a path in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/678236/how-to-get-the-filename-without-the-extension-from-a-path-in-python)

Comment: Try `os.path.splitext(os.path.basename(file))[0] + ".html"`

Comment: @xmojmr, thanks for your useful answer