# Loading multiply csv in pandas dataframe array with index as file name

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have tried this:

```
>>> df = [pd.read_csv(x,header=None,names=["L1","L2","cache","cached","result"]) for x in iglob(os.path.join("test","**","*.csv"), recursive=True)]
>>> df
[   L1  L2  cache  cached  result
0   0   0      0       0       0
1   1   2      3       4       5
2   1   1      1       1       1
3   2   2      2       2       2
4   4   4      4       4       4,    L1  L2  cache  cached  result
0   1   2      3       4       5
1   1   2      3       4       5
2   3   4      5       6       7
3   2   1      3       2       4]
```

The folder structure is:

```
test
|
|_______ wait
         |
         |______ 0.2322.csv
         |______ 1.234.csv
```

The two files contain:
**0.2322.csv**

```
0,0,0,0,0
1,2,3,4,5
1,1,1,1,1
2,2,2,2,2
4,4,4,4,4
```

**1.234.csv**

```
1,2,3,4,5
1,2,3,4,5
3,4,5,6,7
2,1,3,2,4
```

When I am trying to access the dataframes from the `df` array, I have to call it with the index values as `0,1` i.e. `df[0] and df[1]`.

But I want to call the dataframe of the respective files with there file name as index as `df["0.2322"]` and `df["1.234"]`. But I am not getting a clue how that is possible. Please let me know what I can do to achieve what I expect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need dictionary comprehension with parse filename without extension:

```
import os

#https://stackoverflow.com/a/678242
df = {os.path.splitext(x)[0]: pd.read_csv(x,header=None,names=["L1","L2","cache","cached","result"]) for x in iglob(os.path.join("test","**","*.csv"), recursive=True)}
```

EDIT:

```
#https://stackoverflow.com/a/37760212
df = {os.path.splitext(os.path.basename(x))[0]: pd.read_csv(x,header=None,names=["L1","L2","cache","cached","result"]) for x in iglob(os.path.join("test","**","*.csv"), recursive=True)}
```

Comment: I guess that is the thing. Let me try it out please

Comment: What I am getting it this:`{'test\\wait\\1.234':    L1  L2  cache  cached  result` but I only what to have the `1.234`

Comment: @JafferWilson - Sorry, added 2 solutions, but I think `os.path.splitext(x)[0]` should working nice.