# Python string alphabet removal?

Tags: python, string, pycharm

So in my program, I am reading in files and processing them.

My output should say just the file name and then display some data

When I am looping through files and printing output by their name and data,

it displays for example: `myfile.txt`. I don't want the `.txt` part. just `myfile`.

how can I remove the `.txt` from the end of this string?

Comment: myfile.txt.replace(".txt","")

Comment: There are some answers here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/678236/how-to-get-the-filename-without-the-extension-from-a-path-in-python

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to get the filename without the extension from a path in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/678236/how-to-get-the-filename-without-the-extension-from-a-path-in-python)

Comment: In the future, please find a better title for your post. See: [ask].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well if you only have .txt files you can do this

```
file_name = "myfile.txt"
file_name.replace('.txt', '')
```

This uses the built in replace functionality. You can find more info on it [here](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-string-replace/)!

Comment: What if the file does not end with `.txt`?

Comment: @chrisbyte you could also split on the "." and just print the 1st result in the list it returns

Comment: Periods are legal in file names, and some files can be called `my.file.txt`. It would only return the `my`

Comment: @chrisbyte the split method returns a list so in that case you can remove the last item in the list and reconstruct the remaining items with a .join()

Answer (score 2):

The best way to do it is in the example

```
import os

filename = 'myfile.txt'

print(filename)
print(os.path.splitext(filename))
print(os.path.splitext(filename)[0])
```

More info about this very useful builtin module

https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/os.path.html

Comment: Thanks for your input, but since I am not using os. I used the one below.

Answer (score 2):

The answers given are totally right, but if you have other possible extensions, or don't want to import anything, try this:

```
name = file_name.rsplit(".", 1)[0]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `pathlib.Path` which has a `stem` attribute that returns the filename without the suffix.

```
>>> from pathlib import Path
>>> Path('myfile.txt').stem
'myfile'
```