# How to edit the filename of a path string

Tags: python, path

I have a list of file paths eg:

```
file_paths = [
    'repo/batcha/somefile.txt',
    'repo/batcha/someotherfile.txt',
]
```

I want to loop over then and add an id to each filename.

```
for _id, path in enumerate(file_paths):
    <add _id to filename>
```

With an expected output something like:

```
[
    'repo/batcha/node1_somefile.txt',
    'repo/batcha/node2_someotherfile.txt',
]
```

I can of course use `filename.split('/')` on these examples to get at the filename part. I would like to know whether there is, however, a solution using something like os.path that could consistently extract the filename portion of a path in an os independent manner.

Comment: What about [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47496703/9758194) answer? Otherwise, maybe [this](https://regex101.com/r/oRsynX/2) regular expression?

Comment: pathlib is a good recommendation

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To keep your code OS independent, you can use os.sep which is '\' in windows and '/' in linux/unix systems. Below is just an example how can you break and reconstruct paths again.

```
for _id, path in enumerate(file_paths):
    leafs = path.split('/')
    new_path = os.sep.join(leafs)
    print(new_path)
```