# How to display a variable without a specific part?

Tags: python, variables

So, i have a variable, for example `dir = "Crypter.aes"`. I need to variable like `dir`, but without `.aes`. What gotta I do for that? I use directory parser, that make many `dir` with file name in that directory, and for each file I need to remove a certain part at the end - `.aes`

Comment: `dir = dir.split('.')[0]`?

Comment: Beside the point, but don't use `dir` as a variable name since it shadows the [builtin `dir`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#dir).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to get the filename without the extension from a path in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/678236/how-to-get-the-filename-without-the-extension-from-a-path-in-python)

Comment: It doesn't work with my script. I make script with pyAesCrypt, that has syntax like ```pyAesCrypt.decryptFile(inputFile, outputFile, password, buffersize)```. Input file is file with ```.aes``` in the end, output file gotta be with out ```.aes```, but when I use this method, I get error " File "..." was not found"

Comment: wjandrea, yes, it is, THX soo

Answer (score 1):

This is a task for the [`os.path`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.path.html) module in the standard library.

```
import os.path

dir, _ = os.path.splitext("Crypter.aes")
```

If you're working a lot with file paths, you also might want to take a look at the [`pathlib`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html) module.

```
from pathlib import Path

dir = Path("Crypter.aes").stem
```