# need help to extract character with python regex

Tags: python, regex

I am trying to extract the letters out of string, but I can't get it done correctly. Any help will be very much appreciated.

String: `20200702_abcd_ef_aed_usd_cdee_hgd.csv`
Expected: `abcd_ef_aed_usd_cdee_hgd`
Actual: `_abcd_ef_aed_usd_cdee_hgd`

Here is the code, any help can remove the leading `_`?

```py
import re
re.search('[A-Z_]+', "20200702_abcd_ef_aed_usd_cdee_hgd.csv").group()
```

Comment: @Skycc Your code absolute not working. It is just the way Jennifer Stone write in the question.

Comment: Are you after `(?<=_).*?(?=\.)`

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
re.search('[a-z][a-z_]+', "20200702_abcd_ef_aed_usd_cdee_hgd.csv").group()
```

Answer (score 1):

```
import re
x = "20200702_abcd_ef_aed_usd_cdee_hgd.csv"
y = re.search(r"[a-zA-Z][_A-Za-z]+",x)
print(y[0])
```

as you don't need any underscore at the starting of the string you have to specify i.e, `[a-zA-Z]` and then follows the rest `[_a-zA-z]+`,
correction is add `[a-zA-Z]` at the starting.

Answer (score 0):

You do not actually have to rely on a regex here. You may [get the file name without extension](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/678236/how-to-get-the-filename-without-the-extension-from-a-path-in-python), and then split with `_` into two parts and get the last one:

```
import os
s = "20200702_abcd_ef_aed_usd_cdee_hgd.csv"
print( os.path.splitext(s)[0].split('_', 1)[-1] )
```

With regex, you might also try a `re.sub` solution that will also make sure only the digits + `_` are removed from the start:

```
re.sub(r'^\d+_|\.[^.]*$', '', s)
```

Or, if no digit checking is necessary:

```
re.sub(r'^[^_]+_|\.[^.]*$', '', s)
```

See a [Python demo](https://ideone.com/28hg9J) and the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/H6HPIU/2).

**Details**

- `^[^_]+_` - start of string, one or more chars other than `_`
- `|` - or
- `\.[^.]*$` - `.`, any 0 or more chars other than `.` and then an end of string.