# How can I extract filename from a pptx file and use that name to create a text file

Tags: python-3.x

How can I extract the filename from a .pptx file and use that name to create a text file?
I am using this code to read the .pptx file:
`f = open(r”dir/path/filename.pptx“,”r”)`

Comment: I have filename.pptx. 
I want to create a new text file with filename.txt as name

Comment: Hi, perhaps use `os.path.splitext(os.path.basename('/my/path'))[0]`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to get the filename without the extension from a path in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/678236/how-to-get-the-filename-without-the-extension-from-a-path-in-python) Did try any kind of research on this problem before posting here? This is a very common issue with many sources online...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can extract filename of the '.pptx' file as follows:

```
import os
filename = [file for file in os.listdir("dir/path/") if file.endswith('.pptx')][0]
```

Then use it to name file as:

```
with open(filename.split('.')[0]+'.txt', 'w') as f:
    pass
```