# extrapolate substring specifying initial and final values

Tags: python, string, substring

I would like to extrapolate the number part (379022420) from a this string:

```
'../input/predict-volcanic-eruptions-ingv-oe/train/379022420.csv'
```

I would like to do it specifiyng the initial value and the final value, i.e.

```
start = train/
end = .csv
```

this because I need to use it for several others strings and I would like to do it through a loop.

Comment: So is always going to be a number? Or could it be anything?

Comment: Always numbers, all the string are similar to the one showed, for this reason I would like to specify the initial value,that is always train/ and the final value, that is always .csv

Comment: there are better ways to extract file name without extension if that is what you want

Comment: @buran Ok, can you please share them with me?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to get the filename without the extension from a path in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/678236/how-to-get-the-filename-without-the-extension-from-a-path-in-python)

Comment: mmm not really, it is useful to remove the extension but I need just the number part, not all the string

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use the `.split()` function

```py
textList = [...]
for i in textList:
   i.split('train/')
   desiredValue = i[1].split(".")
   desiredValue = desiredValue[0]
```

Comment: There is a way to specify also that when it encouter 'csv' it needs to stop saving the value?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you can search the strings with `re` module:

```
import re

strings = [
    '../input/predict-volcanic-eruptions-ingv-oe/train/379022420.csv'
    # ... other strings
]

pattern = re.compile(r'(?<=train/)(\d+)(?=\.csv)')

for s in strings:
    m = pattern.search(s)
    if m:
        print(m.group(1))
```

Prints:

```
379022420
```