# Filtering files with same name from 2 directories into third folder if the name is same

Tags: python-3.x

I have 2 directories, one with .json and one with .png files. I need to check if the png has a json file in the second folder with the same name and if yes, i need to put that png in a third folder.

I need to make a Python script (3.7) for doing that. Since I don't use Python usually I have a problem of implementing that. Also the names of files saved to the third directory should be saved as increasing numbers ("1.png", "2.png", "3.png" ...).

My idea was to do something like this:

```
import os

for name in os.listdir(directory):
    for filename in os.listdir(directory2):
        # checking if filename in directory2 with the name from the first directory
        # if the name is same, save it in the third directory
        # else continue
```

Is it possible to implement that with the os library because I didn't find a solution for that. If not, how can I solve this?

Comment: Yes you can do with functions within os. Checkout this post:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/678236/how-to-get-the-filename-without-the-extension-from-a-path-in-python  BTW do not use double layer loop. Use a dictionary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `os` and `shutil`:

```py
import os
import shutil

dir1 = '<path of the folder>'
dir2 = '<path of the folder>'
dir3 = '<path of the folder>'

# Create destination folder
os.makedirs(dir3, exist_ok=True)

i = 1
for filename in next(os.walk(dir1))[2]:
    fname, extension = os.path.splitext(filename)
    if extension == '.png' and os.path.exists(os.path.join(dir2, f'{fname}.json')):
        shutil.copyfile(os.path.join(dir1, filename), os.path.join(dir3, f'{i}.png'))
        i += 1
```