# Find each keyword in a text file and record with file name

Tags: python, pandas, list, append, inner-join

I have downloaded ~100 stored procs as .txt files from SQL Server. From these txt files I am looking to record every iteration of a keyword beginning with "XXX". So every time the word occurs in the script, it is placed into a dataframe with the name of the file next to it.

For example:

> File: fileone
>
> Script: "AAA BBB CCC XXXA XXXB DDD"

Would return:

| Keyword | File |
| --- | --- |
| XXXA | fileone |
| XXXB | fileone |

I have a dataframe of my keywords and would like to loop this across all of my files.

Ideally, resulting in an output that looks like:

| Keyword | File | File | File |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| XXXA | fileone | filetwo | filethree |
| XXXB | fileone | filetwo | null |
| XXXC | null | null | filethree |

Below is the code that I am using to return the keyword list: I am doing this by taking the combined script of all of my stored procs (copy and pasted into one txt file) and finding all of the keywords that being with "XXX".

```
with open(allprocs, 'r') as f:
for line in f:
    for word in line.split():
        if word.startswith('XXX.'):
            list.append(word)

new_List = pd.unique(list).tolist()
df1 = pd.DataFrame(new_List,
              columns = ['Tables'])
df1 = df1.drop_duplicates()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I don't have your data, I provide a solution that generates a dataset for a directory containing some python scripts, and I am looking for words starting with `n`.

First we need a list of all relevant files in that directory, so we can access them one-by-one and avoid manually copying and pasting contents.

```py
import glob
files = glob.glob("/PATH/*.py")
```

Next we'll generate a [tidy](https://towardsdatascience.com/whats-tidy-data-how-to-organize-messy-datasets-in-python-with-melt-and-pivotable-functions-5d52daa996c9) dataframe with a keyword-file mapping.

```py
import pandas as pd
import nltk  # optional
collect = []
for file in files:
    with open(file, 'r') as file_handle:
        for line in file_handle:
            # for word in line.split():
            for word in nltk.word_tokenize(line): # optional
                if word.startswith('n'):
                    collect.append({'keyword': word, 'filename': file.split('/')[-1]})

words_files_tidy = pd.DataFrame.from_records(collect).drop_duplicates()
```

This gets us a dataframe you first described.

| keyword | filename |
| --- | --- |
| XXXA | fileone |
| XXXC | fileone |
| XXXB | filetwo |
| XXXC | filetwo |
| XXXA | filethree |

---

Finally, pivot the dataset to get the desired result.

```py
final_df = words_files_tidy.pivot(index='keyword', columns='filename', values='filename').reset_index()
```

Which will get you

| Keyword | fileone | filetwo | filethree |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| XXXA | fileone | null | filethree |
| XXXB | fileone | filetwo | null |
| XXXC | null | null | filethree |

rename the columns if necessary.

Comment: This is great and does exactly what I want it to. If I wanted to return just the filename and not the entire path, how would I do this? One way I'd think to do it would be to write something like 
"file_handle = file_handle[61:-20]"
would this work?

Comment: Solved this by adding "filename = file[61:-20]" under the with open line and changing the  collect.append line to have " 'filename': filename " which cut off the C:users...... and the .txt extensions. Thank you @ufos for the help

Comment: @smitty_werben_jagerm don't use any hacks like that! You can see my quick-and-dirty `file.split('/')[-1]`, which is more reliable. Generally, refer to this thread https://stackoverflow.com/questions/678236/how-to-get-the-filename-without-the-extension-from-a-path-in-python