# Having issue with downloading files with same name from outlook using Python. Only one file is showing on folder

Tags: python, file, outlook, download

```
from datetime import date
import os
import email

import win32com.client
import pathlib
import glob
import re
from pathlib import Path

path = os.path.expanduser(file_location + "/" +date_file)
 
outlook = win32com.client.Dispatch("Outlook.Application").GetNamespace("MAPI")
inbox = outlook.GetDefaultFolder(6)  #from inbox
inbox = inbox.Folders['folder 1'] #Folder inside Inbox Folder

today = datetime.date.today()        #from todays date
received_dt = date.today() - timedelta(days=1)

messages = inbox.Items          

def saveattachments():                                                  # subject= subject line t0 be inserted here. 
    for message in messages:                   
        if message.Unread:# and message.Senton.date() == today: 
            for attachment in message.Attachments:
                print(attachment.FileName)                                     # shows the file name to be downloaded
                attachment.SaveAsFile(os.path.join(path, str(attachment)))     #saves it the desired location
                if message.Unread:
                    message.Unread = False                                         #returns the email to read status
                
                
saveattachments()
```

I want to download all the files from unread emails. But files with same name gets replaced somehow only one file name is showing.

Example-

| Files from outlook | filename which gets saved on desk folder |
| --- | --- |
| a_file | a_file |
| b_file | b_file |
| c_file | c_file |
| a_file | d_file |
| b_file |  |
| b_file |  |
| a_file |  |
| b_file |  |
| c_file |  |
| d_file |  |

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is very much expected behavior. [There can be only one](https://www.meme-arsenal.com/memes/d0e24b03f9b65910584d944e7de63694.jpg) file with a specific name in a specific folder. You will need to implement some logic to see if the file already exists, and rename it.

See below for a simple example:

```py
import os


def autorename(filename):
    """recursive function to add " (copy)" to a filename if it already exists.
    """
    if os.path.isfile(filename):
        newfilename = f"{os.path.splitext(filename)[0]} (copy){os.path.splitext(filename)[1]}"
        return autorename(newfilename)
    else:
        return filename
```

For the `os.path.splitext()` part, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/678242/9267296).

---

**EDIT**

To add this to your code, you need to change this line:

```py
attachment.SaveAsFile(os.path.join(path, str(attachment)))
```

to this:

```py
attachment.SaveAsFile(autorename(os.path.join(path, str(attachment))))
```

so it generates a new filename if the file already exists

Comment: Thanks for your response. Yes changing the file name in the process will help. I do understand your code but fail to implement . I'm confused how to infuse your code to mine.

Comment: See my edit at the bottom

Comment: This works! Thank you sooooo muuchhh :D