# filename as key in dictionary - pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have around 100 .csv files in a folder.
They are named like AA.csv, BB.csv, CC.csv.....

I have used the below command to load all the files into the dataframe

```
import pandas as pd
import glob

df = pd.concat(map(pd.read_csv, glob.glob('/Users/redman/stock-data/*.csv')))
```

How can i store them in a dictionary with using the filename as the key???
Here the dictionary key will be "AA", "BB", "CC".
Any suggestions would be great.

Comment: Instead of 1 big dataframe you want separate dataframes keyed by file name?

Comment: yes you are correct

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We can use a dictionary comprehension:

```
import glob

import pandas as pd

d = {f: pd.read_csv(f)
     for f in glob.glob('/Users/redman/stock-data/*.csv')}
```

We can use [`Path.stem`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html#pathlib.PurePath.stem) and [`Path.glob`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html#pathlib.Path.glob) if we only want the file name and not the extension or path:

```
import glob
from pathlib import Path

import pandas as pd

d = {f.stem: pd.read_csv(f.resolve())
     for f in Path('/Users/redman/stock-data/').glob('*.csv')}
```

---

Complete Working Example with Generated Sample Data:

```
import glob
from pathlib import Path
from pprint import pprint

import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

# Generate Sample Directory and csv
np.random.seed(26)
Path('./stock-data').mkdir(exist_ok=True)
for f in ['AA', 'BB', 'CC']:
    pd.DataFrame(
        np.random.randint(1, 100, (3, 5)),
    ).to_csv(f'./stock-data/{f}.csv', index=False)

# Build Dictionary
d = {f.stem: pd.read_csv(f.resolve())
     for f in Path('./stock-data/').glob('*.csv')}
pprint(d)
```

`d`:

```
{'AA':     0   1   2   3   4
0  54  63   7  49  66
1  84  78  91  33  69
2  99  46  18  56  54,
 'BB':     0   1   2   3   4
0  90  53  89  22  31
1  16  43  24  48  92
2  57  83  48  13  48,
 'CC':     0   1   2   3   4
0  17  13  61  77  84
1  20  30  52  29  82
2  45  18  60  53  71}
```

Comment: d = {os.path.basename(f): pd.read_csv(f)
     for f in glob.glob('/Users/rakshahegde/Downloads/stock_data-2/*.csv')}
print(d)

Comment: this works. but the key is "AA.csv". How can i remove the .csv part?

Comment: The pathlib option with Path.stem would be my recommendation. But there are a bunch of options here [How to get the filename without the extension from a path in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/678236/15497888). A bit long, but `os.path.splitext(os.path.basename(f))[0]` like in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1228618/15497888)