# expected str, bytes or os.PathLike object, not list ( want to get file names from list)

Tags: python

I'm trying to get only the file name without extension, what I still get this error even though it's what it says in the book I'm trying to read.

```
import os
import re
stringA =[fname.rsplit(' ',0)[0] for fname in os.listdir("C:\\Users\\Desktop\\New folder\\New folder\\")]
stringA1 = os.path.splitext(os.path.basename(stringA))[0]
```

I get this error:

```
~\Anaconda3\lib\ntpath.py in basename(p) 
    214 def basename(p): 
    215 """Returns the final component of a pathname""" 
--> 216 return split(p)[1] 
    217 
    218 
~\Anaconda3\lib\ntpath.py in split(p) 
    183 Return tuple (head, tail) where tail is everything after the final slash. 
    184 Either part may be empty.""" 
--> 185 p = os.fspath(p) 
    186 seps = _get_bothseps(p) 
    187 d, p = splitdrive(p) 
TypeError: expected str, bytes or os.PathLike object, not list
```

Comment: Perhaps you need to apply the `[0]` to `stringA` inside the `basename()` function.

Comment: `stringA` is obvouisly a list (`[...]`). The error is pretty clear that `basename` expects a string, bytes or `PathLike` object, not a list... What are you trying to do?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to get the filename without the extension from a path in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/678236/6045800)

Answer (score 1):

In the first line of your code - you want to split by a `.` and not by spaces as a `.` would be the separator between a filename and its extension.

Also, you want to pass a value of `1` to the `maxsplit` argument - meaning that you want at most 1 split. 0 means you don't want to split the input at all

```
stringA =[fname.rsplit('.',1)[0] for fname in os.listdir("C:\\Users\\Desktop\\New folder\\New folder\\")]
```

Comment: But i have lots of file in this folder and just want to extract only file names of every file

Comment: Like that   [ 'Beed 1-2-22 to 7-2-22.xlsx',
 'Doth_01 01 22_02 07 22.xlsx',
 'Foadd.xlsx',
 'Spy_010122_020722.xlsx',
 'Viner_1.1.22_3.31.22_as of 2.8.22.xlsx',
 'Vox Me_2.1.2022_2.7.22.xlsx']

Answer (score 1):

To get all the the files in a folder only:-

```
import os
folder = "C:\\Users\\Folder"

for files in os.listdir(folder):
    filelist = (files.partition(".")[0])
    print(filelist)
```

To get all the files in folder and subfolders, use this:-

```
import os
folder = "C:\\Users\\Folder"

for root, dir, files in os.walk(folder):
    for file in files:    
        filelist = (file.partition(".")[0])
        print(filelist)
```

Comment: But i have lots of file in this folder and just want to extract only file names of every file.

Comment: Like that   [ 'Beed 1-2-22 to 7-2-22.xlsx',
 'Doth_01 01 22_02 07 22.xlsx',
 'Foadd.xlsx',
 'Spy_010122_020722.xlsx',
 'Viner_1.1.22_3.31.22_as of 2.8.22.xlsx',
 'Vox Me_2.1.2022_2.7.22.xlsx']

Comment: Thanks but i need only text

Comment: Bro! You will get text only. Even if you you use any of the method. To get the files in the subfolder of a folder. You can use the second one.

Comment: By the way, did you get what you are lokking for?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to obtain only the filename, without its extension and without the preceding path, you can combine the use of the `os.path.splitext` function with the `split` function from the string type:

```
>>> import os
>>> p = 'c/folder/folder/file.txt'
>>> os.path.splitext(p)[0].split('/')[-1]
'file'
```