# find common files between two directories - exclude file extension

Tags: python, bash, jupyter

I have two directories with files that end in two different extensions:

***Folder A called profile (1204 FILES)***

```
file.fasta.profile
file1.fasta.profile
file2.fasta.profile
```

***Folder B called dssp (1348 FILES)***

```
file.dssp
file1.dssp
file2.dssp
file3.dssp #<-- odd one out
```

I have some files in `folder B` that are not found in `folder A` and should be removed for example `file3.profile` would be deleted as it is not found in `folder A`. I just want to retain those that are common in their filename, but excluding extension to end up with **1204 files in both**
I saw some bash lines using diff but it does not consider this case, where the ones I want to remove are those that are not found in the corresponding other file.

Comment: use glob with https://stackoverflow.com/questions/678236/how-do-i-get-the-filename-without-the-extension-from-a-path-in-python

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Python version:

**EDIT: now suports multiple extensions**

```
#!/usr/bin/python3

import glob, os

def removeext(filename):
    index = filename.find(".")
    return(filename[:index])

setA = set(map(removeext,os.listdir('A')))
print("Files in directory A: " + str(setA))

setB = set(map(removeext,os.listdir('B')))
print("Files in directory B: " + str(setB))

setDiff = setA.difference(setB)
print("Files only in directory A: " + str(setDiff))

for filename in setDiff:
    file_path = "A/" + filename + ".*"
    for file in glob.glob(file_path):
        print("file=" + file)
        os.remove(file)
```

Does pretty much the same as my bash version above.

- list files in A
- list files in B
- get the list of differences
- delete the differences from A

---

**Test output**, done on Linux Mint, bash 4.4.20

```
mint:~/SO$ l
drwxr-xr-x 2 Nic3500 Nic3500 4096 May 10 10:36 A/
drwxr-xr-x 2 Nic3500 Nic3500 4096 May 10 10:36 B/

mint:~/SO$ l A
total 0
-rw-r--r-- 1 Nic3500 Nic3500 0 May 10 10:06 file1.fasta.profile
-rw-r--r-- 1 Nic3500 Nic3500 0 May 10 10:06 file2.fasta.profile
-rw-r--r-- 1 Nic3500 Nic3500 0 May 10 10:14 file3.fasta.profile
-rw-r--r-- 1 Nic3500 Nic3500 0 May 10 10:36 file4.fasta.profile
-rw-r--r-- 1 Nic3500 Nic3500 0 May 10 10:06 file.fasta.profile
mint:~/SO$ l B
total 0
-rw-r--r-- 1 Nic3500 Nic3500 0 May 10 10:05 file1.dssp
-rw-r--r-- 1 Nic3500 Nic3500 0 May 10 10:06 file2.dssp
-rw-r--r-- 1 Nic3500 Nic3500 0 May 10 10:06 file3.dssp
-rw-r--r-- 1 Nic3500 Nic3500 0 May 10 10:05 file.dssp


mint:~/SO$ ./so.py
Files in directory A: {'file1', 'file', 'file3', 'file2', 'file4'}
Files in directory B: {'file1', 'file', 'file3', 'file2'}
Files only in directory A: {'file4'}
file=A/file4.fasta.profile


mint:~/SO$ l A
total 0
-rw-r--r-- 1 Nic3500 Nic3500 0 May 10 10:06 file1.fasta.profile
-rw-r--r-- 1 Nic3500 Nic3500 0 May 10 10:06 file2.fasta.profile
-rw-r--r-- 1 Nic3500 Nic3500 0 May 10 10:14 file3.fasta.profile
-rw-r--r-- 1 Nic3500 Nic3500 0 May 10 10:06 file.fasta.profile
```

Comment: I think there must be a problem with the fact that it is .fasta.profile and not just .fasta pr .profile as here I get: `Files in directory A: {'d1y0pa3.fasta', 'd3nvsa_.fasta', 'd1k8kd1.fasta', 'd1j09a1.fasta', 'd1vh4a_.fasta', 'd2oy9a1.fasta', 'd3ag3h_.fasta', 'd1wtja_.fasta', 'd3mzfa2.fasta', 'd1g2ra_.fasta', 'd1knza_.fasta', 'd2fcwa1.fasta', 'd1a62a1.fasta', 'd2fgqx_.fasta', 'd2idob_.fasta', 'd1mwqa_.fasta', 'd1k8ke_.fasta', 'd1oisa_.fasta', 'd3essa_.fasta', 'd1fn9a_.fasta', 'd2vn6b_.fasta'`
but it is not deleted anything.

Comment: Fixed for multiple extensions.

Comment: I simply get an output of: `Files in directory A: set()
Files in directory B: set()
Files only in directory A: set()` hmph.

Comment: Tested on python 3.6

Comment: finally! I think it worked...but... :1204
    1205 is the results... there is one left out! let me check.

Comment: how can I print the files that are different only considering the filename?

Comment: That is what you get from the "Files only in directory A" output.

Comment: When I use the line: `setDiff = setB.difference(setA)
print("Files only in directory B: " + str(setDiff))` I get `Files only in directory B: set()` and I did try vice-versa just in case... it is strange no? as clearly there is a difference.

Comment: FYI for your next question, include more details.  Ex. running in Jupyter, tag the language you prefer os indicate that you accept both, complete data set for our tests.

Comment: All files in B are included in A, so the difference is empty, hence the empty set `set()`.

Comment: the number of files in dssp is 1205, that is what I put for set A which originally was 1348. while the profile folder or folder B, is what I set for set B. I think it is important to mention that the order in which you put this in matters cause when I flipped the two sets, it does not work. the larger set much be in set A

Comment: I ran it again and I am still getting one extra in set A, I am running this code: `list(set(setA) - set(setB))` and it results empty, why is that?

Comment: I am running this: `!ls /Users/user/Desktop/Desktop/LAB2/prova_training/profile | wc -l
!ls /Users/user/Desktop/Desktop/LAB2/prova_training/dssp | wc -l` to check the length, maybe this is the problem? as running len(setA) and len(setB) I get 1201 for both. it should be 1204 though.

Comment: If you run the script once, it deleted files, so you can't run it over and over again on the same source directories after they have been cleanup once.  As to your wc, impossible to know since I do not have access to your system.

Comment: No, I am running on a new directory each time that I have duplicated... I still get 1201 for Len and 1204 for wc..very strange.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/244643/discussion-between-francesca-c-and-nic3500).

Answer (score 3):

Here is a way to do it:

- for both A and B directories, list the files under each directory, without the extension.
- compare both lists, show only the file that does not appear in both.

Code:

```
#!/bin/bash

>a.list
>b.list

for file in A/*
do
    basename "${file%.*}" >>a.list
done

for file in B/*
do
    basename "${file%.*}" >>b.list
done

comm -23 <(sort a.list) <(sort b.list) >delete.list

while IFS= read -r line; do
    rm -v A/"$line"\.*
done < "delete.list"

# cleanup
rm -f a.list b.list delete.list
```

- `"${file%.*}"` removes the extension
- `basename` removes the path
- `comm -23 ...` shows only the lines that appear only in a.list

**EDIT May 10th**: my initial code listed the file, but did not delete it.  Now it does.

Comment: I like that this shows the list of files that are to be removed, the last line is for the removal yes?

Comment: I just followed it through, it seemed to create the two a.list and b.list files but it created it with the actual name written: `file%.*`. it did this for both.

Comment: Do you want Python or bash solution?  You mention Jupiter in comments to one of the answers, that runs Python great, not sure about all the subtleties of bash (ex. variable expansion like `${file&.*}`. I tested it directly in bash on a Linux box.

Comment: I could run python or bash from Jupiter the same, well at least it seems that way to me

Comment: Can I make this code run in Jupyter though? I ran it through the shell cause I didn't think it would work

Comment: I do not have a Jupyter setup to test it real quick, so YMMV.  It works for me on Linux Mint 20, GNU bash 4.4.20.

Comment: okay I will run it on the shell then...so I create 2 files, a and b, add the list without the file extension to each corresponding list and then find those in common yes?

Comment: do I need to write the entire path even in I am in the directory?

Comment: I am doing `for file in dssp/*` for example, should there be a .*?

Comment: `for file in dssp/*` will list all files under sub-directory `dssp`.  No need to put `*.*`.  `*` matches all, extension included.

Comment: it seems to be working! okay how do I see the final outputs then? or how can I verify it was successful?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/244636/discussion-between-francesca-c-and-nic3500).

Comment: `/bin/ls -c1 A` and `/bin/ls -c1 B` should be the same.

Answer (score 3):

Try this [Shellcheck](https://www.shellcheck.net/)-clean Bash program:

```
#! /bin/bash -p

folder_a=PATH_TO_FOLDER_A
folder_b=PATH_TO_FOLDER_B

shopt -s nullglob
for ppath in "$folder_a"/*.profile; do
    pfile=${ppath##*/}
    dfile=${pfile%.profile}.dssp
    dpath=$folder_b/$dfile
    [[ -f $dpath ]] || echo rm -v -- "$ppath"
done
```

- It currently just prints what it would do.  Remove the `echo` once you are sure that it will do what you want.
- `shopt -s nullglob` makes globs expand to nothing when nothing matches (otherwise they expand to the glob pattern itself, which is almost never useful in programs).
- See [Removing part of a string (BashFAQ/100 (How do I do string manipulation in bash?))](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/100#Removing_part_of_a_string) for information about the string manipulation mechanisms used (e.g. `${ppath##*/}`).

Answer (score 3):

With `find`:

```sh
find 'folder A' -type f -name '*.fasta.profile' -exec sh -c \
'! [ -f "folder B/$(basename -s .fasta.profile "$1").dssp" ]' _ {} \; -print
```

Replace `-print` by `-delete` when you will be convinced that it does what you want.

Or, maybe a bit faster:

```sh
find 'folder A' -type f -name '*.fasta.profile' -exec sh -c \
'for f in "$@"; do [ -f "folder B/$(basename -s .fasta.profile "$f").dssp" ] || echo rm "$f"; done' _ {} +
```

Remove `echo` when you will be convinced that it does what you want.

Comment: it does not seem to work, I realised that its .fasta.profile, not just .profile, I added the .fasta portion in, but it does not change anything.

Comment: Edited accordingly but please edit your question and provide an accurate description of your problem. Remember that SO is not just a Q&A site. It is also a knowledge database. It is important that questions and answers can be useful to others.

Comment: I tried it, btw I am running with Jupyter. it does not print anything, but does not create any error either. It seems to be working on something however as it looks as though it is loading something, but the output is empty.

Comment: just to show: the files are titled like such: d1ayoa_.dssp, d1a62a1.dssp --- d1ayoa_.fasta.profile, d1a62a1.fasta.profile

Comment: From which directory do you launch these `find` commands? It must be from the parent directory of your two folders. By the way, did you check the folder names? Is it really `folder A` and `folder B` with a space between `folder` and `A/B`? If not you must adapt the `find` commands.

Comment: And **please edit your question**. If you don't it could be downvoted and closed before you will receive a working answer.