# How to pull the file name from a url using javascript/jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

A certain variable might contain a relative path or an absolute path.  Either way, I need to be able to pull the filename from the variable:

```
http://www.somesite.com/dir1/dir2/filename.gif
/dir1/dir2/filename.gif
```

The directory structure is also arbitrary.  So basically given either of the url's above (with arbirtrary directory structure) I need to pull 'filename.gif'.  Thanks in advance

Comment: See also possible duplicate: [How to get the file name from a full path using JavaScript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/423376/how-to-get-the-file-name-from-a-full-path-using-javascript)

Answer (score 64):

```
var index = yourstring.lastIndexOf("/") + 1;
var filename = yourstring.substr(index);
```

Comment: is this faster than using a regex?

Comment: I'm getting `/filename.gif` instead of `filename.gif`. The index should be incremented by 1 before calling substr.

Comment: Use `slice` instead of `substr`: [JavaScript: Slice, Substring, or Substr?](http://www.jacklmoore.com/notes/substring-substr-slice-javascript/)

Comment: @Gregoire What happens if the / is a \ how do you get the file name then?

Comment: @Pomster var index = yourstring.lastIndexOf("\\") + 1;

Comment: Thank you for not using a regex.

Comment: this doesn't handle the edge case where URL contains a nested encoded URL. You could end up with a value like this `?url=https%3A%2F%2Ffoobar%2Fimage.jpg` when you actually wanted `image.jpg`. I posted my [answer that handles this case](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68264052/8234457)

Answer (score 27):

Shorter way

```
var filename = window.location.href.substr(window.location.href.lastIndexOf("/")+1);
```

Comment: This does not support filename.php/arctile/slug-name (it will return slug-name)

Comment: I would recommend using [`document.URL`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document.URL?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=DOM%2Fdocument.URL) in place of `window.location.href` when you're only retrieving the value.

Answer (score 13):

```
var filename = url.match(/.*\/(.*)$/)[1];
```

Answer (score 11):

```
var filename= url.split('/').pop()
```

Answer (score 6):

I'd use a regular expression.

```
[^/]*$
```

It selects everything after the last slash until the end. You can expand it to select the extension separately:

```
/([^/]*?)(\.[^\./]*)?$
```

Comment: I find this regex clearer, but it is not written in JavaScript... Here's the full thing: `url.match('[^/]*$')[0]`

Answer (score 4):

```
var path = window.location.pathname;
var filename = path.match(/.*\/([^/]+)\.([^?]+)/i)[1];
```

Use this in the case that you don't want your query string to be part of your filename (which you probably don't).

Comment: Great, but can you expand the functionality of also cutting away the parameters in the end, including a "**?**" ? Thanks

Comment: @JamesCazzetta: maybe overkill for your needs, but this will get you everything you need from a URI: https://gist.github.com/1169555

Answer (score 3):

```
var URL = window.location.pathname; // Gets page name
var page = URL.substring(URL.lastIndexOf('/') + 1);  
alert(page);
```

Answer (score 2):

```
// Extract filename from current page.
var filePath = window.location.pathname;
var fileName = filePath.substr(urlPath.lastIndexOf("/") + 1);
```

Comment: what is urlPath? It's not variable or a window property.

Answer (score 2):

For your examples, substring searching will probably be your best option.

However, if your URIs are actually complex enough, you might try Steven Levithan's [`parseUri`](http://blog.stevenlevithan.com/archives/parseuri):

```
parseUri(uri).file;
```

It has 2 modes and each has its share of quirks, so be sure to [check out the demo](http://stevenlevithan.com/demo/parseuri/js/).

Answer (score 1):

Use a regular expression, something along these lines should do the trick:

```
[^/]+\.[^/]+
```

Although that doesn't cover every possible case, it should be more than suitable for most cases. You can these use:

```
var url = window.location.href;
var regex = new RegExp("[^/]+\.[^/]+");
var fileName = regex.exec(url);
```

Hope that helps

Comment: Nope. That results in a match of `["http:"]`.

Answer (score 1):

```
var filename = /[^\\\/:*?"<>|\r\n]+$/i.exec(window.location.href)[0];
```

Answer (score 1):

thanks sam deng, seems to work but you have a typo my friend:

```
// Extract filename from current page.
var filePath = window.location.pathname;
var fileName = filePath.substr(filePath.lastIndexOf("/") + 1);
```

Comment: thanks for your help, but you should leave this as a comment to the relative answer rather than posting a new one (in future you will be able to suggest an edit to others' answers)

Answer (score 1):

```
    var pathnameArray = window.location.pathname.split("/");
    var nameOfFile = pathnameArray[pathnameArray.length -1];
```

There's probably some overhead I don't know about when considering making an array versus using the substr others have mentioned. So maybe this isn't a great answer but rather a different approach to solving the same problem.

Answer (score 1):

I solved this problem by this:

```
var URL = window.location.pathname; // Gets page name
var page = URL.substring(URL.lastIndexOf('/') + 1); 
// then display your filename to console
console.info(page)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you url is like this:

```
yourdomain.com/app_dev.php
yourdomain.com/app_dev.php/article/2
```

and you want to just pull filename (/app_dev.php) so that you can link to your homepage use this:

```
var filename = window.location.pathname.substr(0, window.location.pathname.indexOf("/", 1));
window.location = filename;
```

Answer (score 0):

My answer handles edge case where the URL is encoded or the URL contains a query value that's an encoded URL, where the `/` becomes `%2F`.

```js
const getImageNameFromURL = (urlInput) => {
  const imageFullnameResult = urlInput.match(/.+(\/|%2F)(.+)/);

  if (!imageFullnameResult) return null;

  const imageFullname = imageFullnameResult[2];

  const imageNameResult = imageFullname.match(
    /.+(jpg|png|svg|jpeg|webp|bmp|gif)/
  );

  if (!imageNameResult) return imageFullname;

  const imageName = imageNameResult[0];

  if (!imageName) return null;

  return imageName;
};

// common URL
const commonURL = 'https://static.tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pub/images/aubrey_plaza.jpg?quality=75&w=1200&h=900&crop=1'

// URL contains query which is an encoded URL which is the actual image.
const urlContainsEncodedURL = 'https://ca-times.brightspotcdn.com/dims4/default/a7ccc15/2147483647/strip/true/crop/2048x1152+0+0/resize/840x473!/quality/90/?url=https%3A%2F%2Fcalifornia-times-brightspot.s3.amazonaws.com%2Fd5%2Fb5%2Fa8bffb00214d8bd8149373c18a6a%2Fla-1467703026-snap-photo'

console.log(getImageNameFromURL(commonURL))
// result: aubrey_plaza.jpg


console.log(getImageNameFromURL(urlContainsEncodedURL))
// result: la-1467703026-snap-photo
```