# split method error in IE

Tags: jquery

I want to get the image name and its extension of a some images with jquery. I use split method.it is ok in firefox but i IE it get the full address of image with domain name so it has some (.)s before getting the (.) of image extension.

is there a better way to do that?
here is the code i use:

```
 var imagename = $("img",this).attr("src").split(".")[0];
 var  imageextension = $("img",this).attr("src").split(".")[1];
```

thanks.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to pull the file name from a url using javascript/jquery?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1302306/how-to-pull-the-file-name-from-a-url-using-javascript-jquery)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
// get the last path fragment
var lastFragment = $('img', this).attr('src').match(/\/([^\/]+)$/)[1];
// split dot fragments
var lastFragmentSplit = lastFragment.split('.');
// name is first
var imageName = lastFragmentSplit[0];
// extension is second
var imageExtension = lastFragmentSplit[1];
```

Note: this simple solution won't work as you expect if you have filenames like `names.with.dots.then.extension.jpg`.

The reason why it doesn't work as you expect in IE is because IE resolves the full, absolute URI when you ask for the `src` even if the original attribute you supply has only a file name. Firefox leaves it intact.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is quite in-efficient. You are querying all the img objects twice. Try:

```
$('img').each(function(index) {
    var parts = this.attr( 'src' ).split( '.' );
    console.log( parts );
});
```

Comment: I think that the problem is that $("img",this).attr("src") is a collection (all the img's of the page). The split() method doens not apply on a collection..

Comment: No, it's because the OP wants to exclude the protocol, domain and path, and only split and use the last fragment. Your answer does basically the same thing as OP's initial code.