# Modify css on certain pages with jquery

Tags: jquery

I need to use Jquery to modify divs on some certain pages that ends with a set of filenames. So for example, if a page ends with filename dispform.aspx, I want jquery to remove a particular div when the page is loaded.

How is this achievable?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> So for example, if a page ends with filename dispform.aspx, I want
>   jquery to remove a particular div when the page is loaded.

Look for file name from `window.location.href` and do something like:

```
if (window.location.href.indexOf('dispform') > 0) {
  $('#divID').remove();
}
```

You need to put that code in `$.ready` handler.

Answer (score 0):

Use can have the current url with :

```
$(location).attr('href');
```

After that, you can use jQuery to remove your div :

```
$("#myDivId").remove();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if (/dispform.aspx$/.test(document.location.toString())) {
 // code to remove element
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It is possible. You can get the current file name from Javascript, jQuery. Please check this post [How to pull the file name from a url using javascript/jquery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1302306/how-to-pull-the-file-name-from-a-url-using-javascript-jquery)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to make sure this works even if there are query parameters or a hash tag, then you can do it like this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    if (window.location.pathname.match(/\/dispform.aspx$/) {
        $("#targetDiv").hide();
    }
});
```

Obviously, you would put your own id in place of #targetDiv.