# jQuery current page via .find() and .each() function

Tags: jquery, html, menu, current-page

I'm trying to make jQuery menu, which can highlight current page. Method is, add class `current` on selected.

Here is html:

```
<div class="menu_items">
<ul class="ul_items" id="navigation">
    <li><a href="index.php">1</a></li>
    <li><a href="index.php?pg=2">2</a></li>
    <li><a href="index.php?pg=3">3</a></li>
    <li><a href="index.php?pg=4">4</a></li>
    <li><a href="index.php?pg=5">5</a></li>             
</ul>
</div>
```

And I tried to make something like that:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#navigation").find("a[href*='"+window.location.href+"']").each(function(){
            $(this).addClass("current")
    });
});
```

Because CSS code is large and etc, complete codes are at [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/WRDQj/)

I think that something isn't properly defined in Jquery part of code. When I try this:

```
var a = $("#navigation").find("a[href*='"+window.location.href+"']");
alert(a);
```

I get [Object] [Object] alert. Can someone help?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

jQuery methods always return a jQuery object. If you want to see what's in it, try `.length` to see how many elements were matched, and `[0]` to access the individual DOM nodes. Or even better - `console.log` it so you can inspect everything in it easily.

Your problem is though that `location.href` returns the whole URL (`http://...`) and your links don't contain that. You could use `location.pathname` to get the path, but the real  correct way to highlight the current page is to do it on the server side. No reason to use JS for something like this.

Comment: Thanks a lot. It helps. I done it with server side, but I`m trying now to same escapeing server side if it is possible. Will see what I get.

Answer (score 0):

Matti is true. But what you can try is the split() method to get the exact value to match the href.

working example: http://jsfiddle.net/ylokesh/AqmHr/2/

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {

    //capture URL
    //var tempURL = window.location.href; 

    var tempURL = "http://www.websiteurl.com/index.php?pg=2"
    var urlMatch = tempURL.split('.com')[1].split('/')[1];
    var hrefVal = $("#navigation a:eq(1)").attr('href');
    $("#navigation").find("a[href='"+hrefVal+"']").html('Current Page');
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
//var url = 'file://one/two/three/index.php?pg=2'; // use this if testing on desktop
var url = window.location.href;
var filepath = url.lastIndexOf("/") + 1;
var matchThis = url.substr(filepath);
$('#navigation').find("a[href*='"+matchThis+"']").addClass('current');
```

No need for `.each`

credit - https://stackoverflow.com/a/1302339/3377049