# How to check if href contains variable

Tags: jquery

I would like to add a class to links that contain the variable "activeLink".

The intention is to highlight the currently active link, which means the link that points to where the user currently is.

Here is what I have tried:

```
//This gets the url parameter
function getQueryVariable(variable) {
    var query = window.location.search.substring(1);
    var vars = query.split("&");
    var pair;
    for (var i=0; i<vars.length; i++) {
        pair = vars[i].split("=");
        if (pair[0] == variable){
            return pair[1];
        }
    }
    return false;
}

//This is where it is stored in variable activeLink
var activeLink = getQueryVariable("pagename");

//This is where I am having trouble
$('.nav a').each(function(index, element) {
  if($('.nav a').attr("href") == activeLink) {
    $(this).addClass('active');
  }
});
```

Comment: Post a [mcve] please. What's `getQueryVariable`?

Comment: `if($('.nav a').attr("href") == activeLink)` should probably be `if(element.attr("href") == activeLink)`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No need for `.each` in this case as [`.find`](https://api.jquery.com/find/) will "search through the descendants of these elements".

Answer based on needing just the filename (and optionally query string but not the full url)

```
//var url = 'file://yi/er/san/page.php?page=4'; // use this variable for testing
var url = window.location.href;
var filepath = url.lastIndexOf("/") + 1;
var matchThis = url.substr(filepath);
$('.nav').find("a[href*='"+matchThis+"']").addClass('active');
```

- credit - https://stackoverflow.com/a/1302339/3377049
- original answer - [jQuery current page via .find() and .each() function](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9150344/3377049)

Comment: Spectacular solution!

Answer (score 0):

You can use `String.prototype.includes()` to find if the link **contains** that string instead of *equals* that string.

```
var activeLink = getQueryVariable("pagename");

$('.nav a').each(function(index, element) {
    if($('.nav a').attr("href").includes(activeLink)) {
        $(this).addClass('active');
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Your function seems right with smal change

try this

```js
 $(document).ready(function(){
   var activeLink = getQueryVariable("pagename");
   $('.nav a').each(function(index, element) {
      if($(this).attr("href").indexOf(activeLink) != -1)
         $(this).addClass('active');
   });
  });
```