# Jquery to get the name of the current html file

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

If you are on `http://www.cnn.com/2012/11/09/opinion/brown-pakistan-malala/index.html` can you get Jquery to grab the `index.html`?

or if you are on `http://www.washingtonpost.com/politics/decision2012/supreme-court-to-review-key-section-of-voting-rights-act/2012/11/09/dd249cd0-216d-11e2-8448-81b1ce7d6978_story.html` have it return `dd249cd0-216d-11e2-8448-81b1ce7d6978_story.html`?

And for non extension defined pages such as this current one `http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13317276/jquery-to-get-the-name-of-the-current-html-file` can it return the last  "file" in the "directory"structure, for example: `jquery-to-get-the-name-of-the-current-html-file`

Comment: Try checking this question out

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1302306/how-to-pull-the-file-name-from-a-url-using-javascript-jquery

Comment: What if the current page is simply `http://stackoverflow.com/`? Do you just want "stackoverflow.com"?

Comment: good clarification, yes, the last of the path name is what I am looking for

Comment: I am using this code document.location.pathname.match(/[^\/]+$/)[0] but when I am in my base link for example `http://stackoverflow.com/` it is throwing error in console, Is there some way to validate it ?

Answer (score 49, accepted):

Although not JQuery, you can access it using the following:

`document.location.href.match(/[^\/]+$/)[0]`

or

`document.location.pathname.match(/[^\/]+$/)[0]` in case of unneeded anchors/hash tags (#).

Comment: I am using this code document.location.pathname.match(/[^\/]+$/)[0] but when I am in my base link for example `http://www.cnn.com` it is throwing error in console, Is there some way to validate it ?

Answer (score 26):

```
location.pathname.split('/').slice(-1)[0]
```

Answer (score 14):

No need for jQuery. This will give you the last segment of the URL path (the bit after the last slash):

```
var href = document.location.href;
var lastPathSegment = href.substr(href.lastIndexOf('/') + 1);
```

Comment: Worked perfectly for me!!

Answer (score 6):

```
function getCurentFileName(){
    var pagePathName= window.location.pathname;
    return pagePathName.substring(pagePathName.lastIndexOf("/") + 1);
}
```