# Changing background color in specific html page with jquery

Tags: jquery, html, css

I want to change the background color of a single HTML page ( ex. contact.html ) but without changing the color of the other pages with jquery. Propably I must make an *if* statement in order to check the url and change the color, but I can't find how.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Please put some code to know what you are talking about and how you are applying the jquery functionality

Answer (score 0):

I guess you use the same script in all your pages?

This way you can check what page the script is currently running in:

```
if (document.location.pathname.match(/[^\/]+$/)[0] == 'contact.html') {
    //... do what ever you only want to do if it's contact.html
    $('body').css("background-color", "yellow");
}
```

Solution from [Jquery to get the name of the current html file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13317276/jquery-to-get-the-name-of-the-current-html-file)