# How to find out the file name with jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

For example, I am executing "index.html"

Something like this:

```
var filename = $.getFileName();

alert(filename);
```

Is it possible to get "index.html" as result in alert?

Comment: possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13317276/jquery-to-get-the-name-of-the-current-html-file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var name = window.location.href.substr(window.location.href.lastIndexOf("/")+1);
```