# How can I remove the parent folders in an array of paths?

Tags: javascript

I am using the following code in order to retrieve sub folder names from the path declared. This works fine but how do I then remove the path name so that the array is a list of just folder names?

```
var myPath = Folder ("Z:/My File System/Me/Work Files/Design");
var folders = getFolders (myPath); 

function getFolders(sourceFolder) {
var folderArray = new Array();
var sFolders = sourceFolder.getFiles ();
var len = sFolders.length;
    for (var i = 0; i < len; i++) {
    var sFolder = sFolders[i];
        if (sFolder instanceof Folder) {
            folderArray.push(sFolder);
        }
    }
return folderArray;
}
```

Instead of returning:

Z:/My File System/Me/Work Files/Design/One
Z:/My File System/Me/Work Files/Design/Two
Z:/My File System/Me/Work Files/Design/Three
Z:/My File System/Me/Work Files/Design/Four

I need:

One
Two
Three
Four

Comment: How to get the path from a `Folder` instance?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/423376/how-to-get-the-file-name-from-a-full-path-using-javascript

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to pull the file name from a url using javascript/jquery?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1302306/how-to-pull-the-file-name-from-a-url-using-javascript-jquery)

Comment: Although I appreciate the answers given, I don't get how to incorporate the solutions into the for loop I gave. Answer 1 seems like it would be a process of creating the string on each iteration and then split it? a bit confused on how to do that. Other answers point to Regexp. Which, if I got the expression right to begin with, I would still need to understand how to incorporate it into a for loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could implement something like this (assuming you can modify the `Folder` prototype, and it stores the path as `this.path`):

```
Folder.prototype.basename = function () {
    return this.path.split('/').pop();
};
```

You would then append the base names to the array:

```
folderArray.push(sFolder.basename());
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use `split()` like this, assuming there are no other slashes towards the end.

```
var sample = 'Z:/My File System/Me/Work Files/Design/Four'.split('/')
var result = sample[sample.length - 1]
```

Answer (score 0):

Regexp the string. Start at the end, and work backward until the first '/'