# Can't get lastIndexOf to work

Tags: javascript

I have this code

```
var url = 'http://sitename.com/category/diving/',
    catName = url.substr(url.lastIndexOf('/') + 1);
```

And when I try to run `alert(catName)` it returns empty string. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: The question is, what do you _want_ it to return?

Comment: Try doing some debugging. For example, do `url.lastIndexOf('/')` and you'll see it returns `35` which is the correct index of the last `/`. From there you can go on to solve the other part of your problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need the category name but you have to remove first the last `/`:

```
var url = 'http://sitename.com/category/diving/';
url = url.substr(0, url.length - 1);
catName = url.substr(url.lastIndexOf('/') + 1);
```

Result:

```
"diving"
```

Answer (score 1):

because you add +1 to the index, so you get undefined string. remove the +1 in the lastIndexOf

Comment: Then it returns `/`. When I add `-1`, it returns `g/`.

Comment: @TomekBuszewski I think you're misunderstanding substr then.

Comment: why not use split('/')[length-1]

Comment: I used it before, but it was slower than this. Perhaps I shoud go back to using it then.

Comment: micro optimization is the source of all evil , especially in a language like JS which speed is not a main feature inside .

Comment: Well, when you have a lot of urls, some ajax etc., you want every ms you can get ;-)

Answer (score 0):

You can use..[parseUri](http://blog.stevenlevithan.com/archives/parseuri)

```
var url = 'http://sitename.com/category/diving/';
url = url.substr(0, url.length - 1);
var filename1 = parseUri(url ).file;--way1
var filename2 = url.match(/.*\/(.*)$/)[1];

Result="diving";
```

[Ways to achieve this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1302306/how-to-pull-the-file-name-from-a-url-using-javascript-jquery)

Comment: Where do you define `parseUri`?

Comment: i just add @DavidSherret