# javascript onclick get image name without path

Tags: javascript, image

I need to copy the name of the image (name + extension) from SRC attribute without path..
HTML:

```
 <input type="text" id="result" /><br /><br />

 <img src="../some_folder/some_folder/photo_name.jpg" onclick="getName()" id="img1" />
```

JS:

```
 function getName() {
    document.getElementById("result").value = document.getElementById("img1").src;
 }
```

This code clones full path of the image.. Path is not static, so I can not just cut rest of "SRC"..
Thanks in advance

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to pull the file name from a url using javascript/jquery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1302306/how-to-pull-the-file-name-from-a-url-using-javascript-jquery)

Comment: `new URL(document.getElementById("img1").src).pathname.split("/").pop()` in 2021.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

You should try this code:

```
var filename = fullPath.replace(/^.*[\\\/]/, '');
```

Your JS function would be:

```
function getName() {
     var fullPath = document.getElementById("img1").src;
     var filename = fullPath.replace(/^.*[\\\/]/, '');
     // or, try this, 
     // var filename = fullPath.split("/").pop();

    document.getElementById("result").value = filename;
 }
```

Comment: One more question please: I'm new in javascript. What if I can not define ID for the IMG, how can I do somethis like this: var fullPath = this.src; i need it, because I have several photos

Comment: try jQuery, it will simplify DOM manipulation so that you can easily access elements without ID/CLASS.

Answer (score 6):

```
document.getElementById("img1").src.split("/").pop().split(".")[0]
```

Comment: OP did want the extension, so you don't need the `.split(".")[0]` bit.

Answer (score 3):

```
function getName() {

    var fullPath = document.getElementById("img1").src;
    var index = fullPath.lastIndexOf("/");
    var filename = fullPath;
    if(index !== -1) {     
        filename = fullPath.substring(index+1,fullPath.length);
    }
    document.getElementById("result").value = filename;
}
```