# Get content between second last and last slash

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a url like the following

http://localhost:8000/test/

What is the tidiest way of getting `test` from this using plain javascript/jQuery?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to pull the file name from a url using javascript/jquery?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1302306/how-to-pull-the-file-name-from-a-url-using-javascript-jquery)

Comment: @dippas but I am trying to get the content between the second last and last slash

Comment: It is the same as the duplicated question. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it easily like following using `split()` method.

```js
var str = 'http://localhost:8000/test/';
var arr = str.split('/'); 

console.log(arr[arr.length-2])
```

Comment: Are you sure last slash is mandatory? Because `http://localhost:8000/test` is perfectly valid URL AFAIK. I think this would be more accurate to handle all possible cases: https://jsfiddle.net/jxu945y9/

Comment: OK. But OP asked for the content between second last and last slash. @A.Wolff

Comment: @Azim Ya and then you answer question as asked but not sure what exactly means OP by `I have a url like the following`. Is it a string? Current  page location? Element href or src? Or what?

Comment: Hm. OP is not saying anything. @A.Wolff

Answer (score 1):

The section of the URL you are referring to is called the path, in Javascript this can be accessed by reading the contents of the `location.pathname` property.

You can then use a regular expression to access only the final directory name (between the last two slashes).

Comment: doesn't return expected results though by itself. Answer is incomplete

Answer (score 0):

Don't you guys like regex? I think it is simpler.

```
s = 'http://localhost:8000/test/';
var content = s.match(/\/([^/]+)\/[^/]*$/)[1];
```

Answer (score 0):

JS `split()` function does magic with `location.pathname` .

```
var str = location.pathname.split('/'); 

var requiredString = str[str.length -2];
```

`requiredString` will contain required string, you may console log it by `console.log(requiredString)` or use it anywhere else in the program.

Answer (score 0):

```
let arr = link.split('/');

let fileName = arr[arr.length - 2] + "/" + arr[arr.length - 1];
```

It will return all data after second last `/`.

Comment: Your answer could be improved by adding more information on what the code does and how it helps the OP.

Answer (score 0):

You can use :

window.location.pathname

returns the path and filename of the current page.

with the split() function

To learn more about window.location in w3 School :

https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_window_location.asp

```
//window.location.pathname return /test

 var path=window.location.pathname.split("/");

 var page=path[0]; //return test`
```