# setting asp hyperlink values JS

Tags: javascript, asp.net

i have an asp hyperlink. and i want to set the innerHTML and outerText of this hyperlink in javascript. how can i achieve this?
i have the following code:

```
var path='c:\folder\file.gif'
var HyperlinkObj = GetElementById('hl');
HyperlinkObj.innerHTML ='<a href='+path+'></a>'; //causes: htmlfile: Unknown runtime error
HyperlinkObj.outerText = 'file.gif'; //how can i get the file name from the path?
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**EDIT:**

The following example shows how you can set the properties of an ASP.NET `HyperLink` control from javascript.

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function setHyperlink(path) {
            var link = document.getElementById("<%= myLink.ClientID %>");
            link.href = path;
            link.innerHTML = getFilenameFromPath(path);
        }

        function getFilenameFromPath(path) {
            return path.replace(/^.*\\/, '');
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
        <div>
            Link: <asp:HyperLink id="myLink" runat="server"></asp:HyperLink><br />
            <input type="button" value="Set Hyperlink" onclick="setHyperlink('c:\\folder\\file.gif')" />
        </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

The `getFilenameFromPath` function comes from the answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/423376/how-to-get-file-name-from-full-path-using-javascript).

**ORIGINAL ANSWER:**

To setup a hyperlink control from the codebehind, you want to make your hyperlink a server control. Assuming you are working in MyPage.aspx, in the front page you would add the following:

```
<asp:HyperLink id="myLink" runat="server"></asp:HyperLink>
```

Then, in the codebehind, say in Page_Load:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if(!Page.IsPostBack)
        SetupLink("myfilename.txt");
}

private void SetupLink(string filename)
{
   myLink.Text = filename;
   //Assumes the file is in the root of your web site
   myLink.NavigateUrl = string.Concat("~/", filename); 
}
```

When you add the `runat="Server"` tag to the hyperlink, the designer should add the reference for this control in the `MyPage.aspx.designer.cs` file. It should look something like this:

```
protected global::System.Web.UI.WebControls.HyperLink myLink;
```

After you have that set up, if you need to access the hyperlink control from Javascript, you can use the `ClientID` property of the myLink control.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
   var link = document.getElementById("<%= myLink.ClientID %>");
   alert(link);
</script>
```

Hope that helps.