# Remove class on IMG if filename contains a string

Tags: jquery

I am fairly new to the jQuery world but I am starting to get a better grasp of things.

I have come across a situation that I need a little help with, I was wondering how I would go about setting up a if statement that looks at a image filename and looks to see if it contains the number `31` , if it does remove a class that is attached.

Thank you ahead of time

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A nice way would be to use a function as an argument for [`.removeClass()`](http://api.jquery.com/removeClass/).

```
$('img').removeClass(function () {
    if (this.src.replace(/^.*\//, '').indexOf('31') > -1) {
         return 'classname';
    }
    return false;
});
```

`.replace(/^.*\//, '')` will return only the filename ([example on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/423376/how-to-get-file-name-from-full-path-using-javascript)), so if there is a `31` in the URL somewhere else (like in `/pix/31/image.jpg`), removal won't happen.

The function should return the classname to be removed if conditions are met, and false otherwise (to indicate nothing should be removed).

You could replace the `img` selector with something more specific if you don't want to check on the whole page (add classes, or specify a [context](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery/#selector-context)).

And the [jsFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/936ZZ/).

Answer (score 8):

Try this:

```
$('img[src*="31"]').removeClass("classname");
```

Edit: actually it searches the whole src attribute, so it's only correct if your URL can't have "31" in it anywhere else.

Answer (score 2):

```
$("img[src*='31']").removeClass("myClass");
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$('img[src*="31"]').each(function() {
    // check if only the filename contains 31
    var filename = $(this).attr('src').substr($(this).attr('src').lastIndexOf('/'));
    if (filename.indexOf('31') != -1) {
        $(this).removeClass(); // will remove all classes the img had
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var img = $('#img_to_look_at');
if ( img.attr('src').indexOf('31') > -1 ) img.removeClass('....');
```

Answer (score -1):

Hope this will solve your problem.

```
if(jQuery("img[src*='31']").size()>0){
    jQuery("img[src*='31']").removeClass('className')
};
```

Comment: Better to use `.length` here.

Comment: The `if` is completely unnecessary. If there are no elements like that, nothing will happen anyways. You also should not use the same selector twice, save it into a variable.