# Upload form - control the filename in the content-disposition?

Tags: javascript, html, internet-explorer, multipartform-data

So apparently I.E. is special in how it forms the multipart/form-data entity in POST request generated by a file upload form.  It sends the entire path instead of just name of a file.  E.g, it might send a path like "C:\Documents and Settings\SomeUser\Desktop\SomeFolder\file.jpg" instead of just "file.jpg".  Is there a CLIENT side method (javascript+html, no flash) to change this behavior to send just the name like Chorme & Firefox do.

Comment: @Thomas --Short answer: I don't need to ask the question to do it server side.

Comment: This is not an solution to my original question, but a workaround:   http://stackoverflow.com/questions/423376/how-to-get-file-name-from-full-path-using-javascript.   Using that method, I can get the short filename and add it as a hidden field to form.