# How to get the value of file upload in textbox?

Tags: jquery

I am working on a website and stuck in the following code. Here I have to get the value of file upload in textbox. I am using jquery code as follows,

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('input[name="product_picture"]').change(function() {
        var selectedValue = $(this).val();
        $('input[name="product"]').val(selectedValue);
    });
});
```

and my textbox and fileupload is,

```
<input type="file" name="product_picture" value="" />
<input type="text" name="product" />
```

But the textbox value is showing with full path like `C:\fakepath\2.png`, But I need to get only `2.png` please help me out.

Comment: Similar question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/423376/how-to-get-file-name-from-full-path-using-javascript

Answer (score 2):

```
var fvals = $(this).val().split('\\');
$('input[name="product"]').val(fvals[fvals.length-1]);
```