# Get filename from string path in javascript?

Tags: javascript, regex, string

How to get the filename from string-path in javascript?

Here is my code

```
var nameString = "/app/base/controllers/filename.js"; //this is the input path string
```

do something here to get only the filename

```
var name = ???   //this value should equal to filename.js
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to get the file name from a full path using JavaScript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/423376/how-to-get-the-file-name-from-a-full-path-using-javascript)

Answer (score 121, accepted):

Try this:

```
   var nameString = "/app/base/controllers/filename.js";
   var filename = nameString.split("/").pop();
```

Comment: Nice to see a simple, nonregex answer.

Comment: The `-1` parameter isn't required (and is ignored in fact). https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/pop

Comment: What if string was `"/app/base/controllers"`?

Comment: @javiniar.leonard you will get "controllers"

Comment: What if the filename contains `\/` ?

Comment: @Cooluhuru you need to use regex

Comment: Path separator could be '\' and it fails.

Answer (score 7):

I don't know why you'd want to us a regex to do this. Surely the following would be sufficient:

```
var nameString = "/app/base/controllers/filename.js";
var nameArray = nameString.split('/');
var name = nameArray[nameArray.length - 1];
```

Comment: One could conceivably use a regex, but I agree with you.  Though a regex could be useful to parse out bad paths.

Comment: This really should be the answer, much more flexible.

Answer (score 1):

Here one more detailed solution using *Regular Expressions*.

**Alternative 1 (generic):** Get a file name (*whatever*) from a string path.

```js
const FILE_NAME_REGEX = /(.+)\/(.+)$/

console.log("/home/username/my-package/my-file1.ts".replace(FILE_NAME_REGEX, '$2'))

console.log("/home/username/my-package/my-file2.js".replace(FILE_NAME_REGEX, '$2'))
```

**Alternative 2 (advanced):** Get *only* a `.ts` file name from a string path.

```js
const JS_PATH = "/home/username/my-package/my-file.spec.js"
const TS_PATH = "/home/username/my-package/my-file.spec.ts"

// RegExp accepts only `.ts` file names in lower case with optional dashes and dots
const TS_REGEX = /(.+)\/([a-z.-]+\.(ts))$/

// a. Get only the file name of a `.ts` path
console.log(TS_PATH.replace(TS_REGEX, '$2'))

// b. Otherwise it will return the complete path
console.log(JS_PATH.replace(TS_REGEX, '$2'))
```

**Note:** Additionally you can test first the regular expressions above in order to validate them before to getting the expected value.

```js
TS_REGEX.test(TS_PATH)
// > true

TS_REGEX.test(JS_PATH)
// > false
```

More information at [MDN - Regular Expressions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp)

Answer (score 0):

a pure regex solution: `\/([^\\\/:*?\"<>|]+)$` 
you will get file name from group 1