# Re-defining string in Javascript

Tags: javascript

Here is my issue hope that someone can help me:

//Declartions

```
var DBName = somthing; // changed dynamically 
var lastPiece;
```

I have this string:

```
"../PeopleImages/GGP/Person_3281.jpg"
```

I want to grab "Person_3281.jpg" piece in the string save it into a variable
lastPiece = Person_3281.jpg;
(The last piece is been change dynamically).

and after that combined it to another string for example:

```
var address = "https://www.google.com/gs/companyCode="+ DBName + lastPiece ;
```

how can I do it in Javascript??

Comment: I answered this, time ago: http://stackoverflow.com/a/11805670/1539655

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var string = "../PeopleImages/GGP/Person_3281.jpg";
var arrFromString = string.split('/');

var lastPiece = arrFromString[arrFromString.length -1];
```

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this with a pretty simple regex:

```
var originalstring = "../PeopleImages/GGP/Person_3281.jpg";
var lastpiece = /[^/]*$/.exec(originalstring)[0];
```

*[reference](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8376542/643482)*