# Jquery fetch the filename from ajax call

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, regex, ajax

I am working on my jquery script to extract the filename to output them in the element when i am fetching the data from ajax call.

When I try this:

```
var photoFilename = filename.split('filename: ');
$('#photo_filename').text(photoFilename1);
$('#photo_dialog').show();
```

I will get something like this:

```
noname.gif attid: 0.2
```

I have also tried this:

```
var photoFilename = filename.split('attid: ');
```

And I have also tried this:

var photoFilename = filename.split(attid);

I will get this:

```
 filename: noname.gif attid: 0.2 filename: what-is-bootstrap.png
```

I have tried to use .replace function to remove the `attid: 0.2` but my variable `attid` are showing a different string so it is hard for me to remove the string for `0.2` when I have `0.1` string.

Here is what I want to achieve:

```
noname.gif
```

Here is the full output:

```
attid: 0.1 filename: noname.gif
attid: 0.2 filename: what-is-bootstrap.png
```

Here is the full code:

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'readMail.php',
    type: 'POST',
    data : {
        mailfolder: mailfolder, 
        email_number: email_number,
        folder: folder,
        readmail: readmail,
        total: total_index
    },
    dataType: 'json',

    success: function(res) {
        filename = res.emailBodyMessage.attached_files;
        var photoFilename = filename.split('filename:');
        $('#photo_filename').text(photoFilename1);
        $('#photo_dialog').show();
   }
});
```

What I am trying to achieve is if I have the string `0.2` using the variable `attid`, I want to fetch the filename `what-is-bootstrap.png`. If I have the string `0.1` using the variable `attid`, I want to fetch the filename `noname.gif` and so on.

Can you please show me an example how I can fetch the filename when my variable `attid` show the string like `0.1`, `0.2` or whatever it is?

Thank you.

Comment: does this post help you maybe? https://stackoverflow.com/a/56342723/5300921

Comment: yes it would help but i dont know how to use regex. Maybe if you could help?

Comment: Is this a homework assignment and if so what are the requirements on the kinds of functions can be used? For example, must you use string-based functions to the exclusion of regex?

Comment: @RobertJones can you add the response you are getting?

Comment: Myanswer was rong I removed it because it will not help anyone. I tried but did not find a solution for finding the filenames yet :(

Comment: @Rustyjim Thank you for letting me to know. Why did Jennis Vaishnav removed his post as he found the solution for finding the filenames? :(