# Javascript Filename function / .html strip

Tags: javascript, html

Good Morning,

I'm using a function I got from another post here:

[How to get the file name from a full path using JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/423376/how-to-get-file-name-from-full-path-using-javascript/423385#423385)

To return the current filename of a webpage

```
var url=window.location.pathname;
var filename = url.replace(/^.*[\\\/]/, '');
alert(filename);
```

and I was curious as to whether it is possible to strip the .html from the end while still using this syntax.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the easiest way will be

```
var filename = url.replace(/^.*[\\\/]/, '').replace(".html", "");
```

Comment: This is the most broswer comprehensive answer of all the answers, so it is the one I'm accepting; however all of the answers are great!

Answer (score 2):

Either specify the extensions you want to manage, to be more restrictive, using:

```
.replace(/^.*[\/](.*)[.](html|jsp|php)/, '$1');
```

Either be more generic, using:

```
.replace(/^.*[\/](.*)[.][a-zA-Z0-9]{2,5}/, '$1');
```

The second one will allow extensions from 2 chars (e.g. `.do`) to 5 chars (e.g. `.xhtml`), which could also contain numbers (e.g. `.php3`).

Comment: @user1821973 I'm not sure this regex is the cause of the IE8 issue you're meeting: it must come from somewhere else in your script. But whatever, I'm glad I could help `;)`

Comment: It is possible, sorry I jumped straight to that conclusion, here let me edit: *The regex probably works in IE8 because IE8 does support regex; however, something unforseen in my script is preventing this statement from working.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a capture clause in replace:

```
var url=window.location.pathname;
alert(url)
var filename = url.replace(/^.*[\\\/](.*).html$/, '$1');
alert(filename);
```