# How do I get the filename from window.location.pathname

Tags: javascript, file

How can I use javascript to get the file name using: window.location.pathname

```
window.location.pathname = G:\AS\Asf\ASF\RSSIMS\welcome.hta
```

id like var x = welcome.hta

How do I get the filename?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't - that's a **server** property that is not exposed to the client.

Comment: what do you think about this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/423376/how-to-get-file-name-from-full-path-using-javascript

Comment: How would the client get a drive-letter path to begin with?