# Get filename from URL without it in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, string, cordova, download

How can I get the filename from a given `URL` in [PhoneGap](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PhoneGap)?

In JavaScript, I used something like this:

```
var uri = encodeURI("http://www.openerpspain.com/descargas-documentacion?download=2");
```

My application downloads the file, but I have to manually set the file name. To illustrate, when I call

```
onclick="descarga('http://www.openerpspain.com/descargas-documentacion?download=2')"
```

this function is run:

```
function descarga(URL){
    var rutaarchivo = "file:///sdcard/data/com.protocolo/test1.pdf";
    alert(rutaarchivo);
    var filetransfer = new FileTransfer();
    filetransfer.download(URL, rutaarchivo,
        function(entry){
          alert("Download complete : " + entry.fullPath);
        },function(error) {
          alert("download error source " + error.source);
        });
}
```

This saves the download to `../com.protocolo`, and its filename is `test.pdf`. I want to be able to save it as the name it is set as on the server (*manual_openerp.230209.pdf*) at the *real* URL, *...//www.openerpspain.com/descargas/manual_openerp.230209.pdf*.

How do I do that?

Answer (score 2):

```
String fileName = url.substring(url.lastIndexOf('/') + 1);
```

where `url` is the complete path of your file.

Comment: Thanks, but if the URL doesn't have filename after "/".
Will be possible to get the filename?

If not, i ll use this , thanks.

Comment: Probably all the url have file name or something after "/"

Comment: Thanks :), i ll use it at the moment :)

Answer (score 2):

Use:

```
url="file:///sdcard/data/com.protocolo/test1.pdf?getVar=value";
url.replace(/\?.*$/,"").replace(/.*\//,"");
```

Answer (score 0):

This is basically asking [How to get the file name from a full path using JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/423376/how-to-get-the-file-name-from-a-full-path-using-javascript). Here, the solution was:

```
var filename = url.replace(/^.*[\\\/]/, '');
```

Answer (score 0):

I added in my URLs parameters. Then in [PhoneGap](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PhoneGap) I used:

```
function getParameterByName( name,href ){
    name = name.replace(/[\[]/,"\\\[").replace(/[\]]/,"\\\]");
    var regexS = "[\\?&]"+name+"=([^&#]*)";
    var regex = new RegExp( regexS );
    var results = regex.exec( href );
    if( results == null )
      return "";
    else
      return decodeURIComponent(results[1].replace(/\+/g, " "));
}
```

**Called from :**

```
var filename = getParameterByName ("nombrefichero", url);
```

So this way I can get example.pdf from:

```
http://www.download.com/fake/example.pdf?nombrefichero=example.pdf
```

And then I can download it, and save it where I want.