# trim a string path using javascript

Tags: javascript

I have the following string:

```
var fileName = $(this).val();
```

this will give me a result:

C:\fakepath\audio_recording_47.wav

what I want is to obtain :  audio_recording_47.wav
so, I need to trim it but I don't know how using javascript
please help

Comment: Have you tried to solve this yourself? Can you pleas share with us some of your attempts?

Comment: [`Get file name from full path`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/423376/how-to-get-the-file-name-from-a-full-path-using-javascript)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
filename.split('\\').reverse()[0];
```

This will split the path by slashes, to obtain each part. Then to keep it simple, i reverse the array, so the last part that you need is now the first; and get the first part.

Or, even more simply: `filename.split('\\').pop()`, which will get the last item from the array.

Comment: Or you could use `pop()`, which would save you the cost of reversing the array. Or you could use `lastIndexOf()` and `substr()`, which would save you the cost of building an array in the first place.

Comment: This won't split a UNIX-style path. You can also `split` with a regular expression, so it could be this: `filename.split(/[\\\/]/g).pop()`.

Comment: @toothbrush For a UNIX path, just replace the \\ with a /.

Answer (score 1):

You can do like this:

```
var fileName = $(this).val();
var path = fileName.split('\\');
var lastValue = path[path.length-1];
console.log(lastValue);//audio_recording_47.wav
```

Or, the shorter way you can do like this:

```
var fileName = $(this).val();
var path = fileName.split('\\').slice(-1);//audio_recording_47.wav
```

Answer (score 1):

You could write a little function to return the base name of the path:

```
function basename(fn) {
    var x = fn.lastIndexOf("\\");

    if (x >= 0) return fn.substr(x + 1);
    return fn;
}

var filename = basename($(this).val());
```

Answer (score 0):

This should do it:

```js
var trimmedFileName = fileName.match(/[^\\]*$/);
```

It matches everything that isn't a `\` until the end of the string.

Comment: Your regular expression is incorrect. `$` marks the end of the string, but `^` marks the beginning of the string.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a regular expression, like this:

```
var fileName = this.value.replace(/(?:[^\\\/]*[\\\/])*/, '');
```

Also, there is no need to use that snippet of jQuery, as `this.value` is both faster and simpler.