# How can I extract the filename of a path

Tags: qt, qml, qtquick2, qt5.4

As stated in the title, I would like to extract the filename of a path (I use `FileDialog` to find a file). If possible without using c++ code.

I'm on Qt 5.4.2 mingw. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Use Javascript and extract the filename from the path in the `onAccepted` handler of your `FileDialog`. See the approach used in [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/423385/2538363).

Comment: Thanks for the correction of my question, and for your answer!

Comment: @BaCaRoZzo That's generally speaking a bad idea.

Comment: @KubaOber well, I totally agree with you! I was just fulfilling the requirement of the OP. Even today, I've used `QFileInfo`. As you said, it's trivial. I should have mentioned it. My fault, sorry. :)

Answer (score 3):

Given how trivial it is to interface QML with any C++ class, it's not a problem that the solution is in C++.

`QFileInfo(filePath).fileName()` does it, if `filePath` is the path returned from the file dialog. You only need to expose it to QML:

```
class Helper : public QObject
{
  Q_OBJECT
public:
  Q_INVOKABLE QString fileNameFromPath(const QString & filePath) const {
    return QFileInfo(filePath).fileName();
  }  
};

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    QGuiApplication app(argc, argv);
    QQuickView view;

    Helper helper;
    view.rootContext()->setContextProperty("appHelper", &helper);

    view.setSource(QUrl::fromLocalFile("foo.qml"));
    view.show();

    return app.exec();
}
```

From QML, simply invoke `appHelper.fileNameFromPath(path)`.