# Get the file name without GET parameters from a full path using JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, regex

Given `/foo/bar/image.jpg?x=1&y=2`, how do I obtain `image.jpg`?

https://stackoverflow.com/a/423385 provides a partial answer, but does not address the GET parameters.

Comment: you could use the information in the location object to get it. http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/obj_location.asp

Comment: @toskv  `/foo/bar/image.jpg?x=1&y=2` is the `src` of an image, and not the page URL.  Does your recommendation still apply?

Comment: oh, that's right. :)

Comment: you can add up to this regex "fullPath.replace(/^.*[\\\/]/, '')"  to avoid everything after the question mark as well.

Comment: @priyavyas  http://jsfiddle.net/d8hepjxu/?

Comment: @user1032531 yes i didn't give you a ready regex. I just gave you the idea to add up something to remove everything after "?" as well. something like this "/\/([^?\/]+(?=\?|$))/gm"

Comment: @all  Testing of each per http://jsfiddle.net/d8hepjxu/3/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use regex as others have suggested, but I find this more readable:

```
var src = '/foo/bar/image.jpg?x=1&y=2';
var img = src.split('/').pop().split('?')[0];
console.log(img);
```

Comment: All answers work, and I can't tell which one is best, but this one is a couple of characters shorter than the rest and maybe more readable (at least for a regex hack like me!).

Answer (score 2):

You can use this regex:

```
/\/([^?\/]+(?=\?|$))/
```

and use captured grpup #1.

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/nR0vK0/1)

```
/        # matches a literal /
[^?\/]+  # matches 1 or more of any char that is not ? or /
(?=\?|$) # is a lookahead to assert that next position is ? or end of line
```

Comment: Includes a leading forward-slash.  Thanks for the explanation,however!

Comment: NO it doesn't include `/` in captured group. I wrote clearly `use captured grpup #1` in my answer.

Answer (score 2):

Since the ? symbol separates the GET parameters from the URL, you can

```
str=str.split("?")[0]
filename = str.replace(/^.*[\/]/, '')
```

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
var str = "/foo/bar/image.jpg?x=1&y=2";
var fileName = str.split('/').slice(-1)[0].split('?')[0];
```

or, for a regex method:

```
var fileName = str.split('/').slice(-1)[0].match(/[^?]+/)[0];
```