# javascript - get the filename and extension from input type=file

Tags: javascript, html, forms, file-upload, input

I have a file upload input and when I click the browse button and select the file, I want the filename and extension to appear in two input text boxes (see code sample).

It works correctly with the extension, but the filename also shows the path which gives me the fakepath warning.

I understand why, but what's a good way to do this and just get the filename into that box.  I don't need the path.

```js
function getoutput(){
    outputfile.value=inputfile.value.split('.')[0];
    extension.value=inputfile.value.split('.')[1];}
```

```html
    <input id='inputfile' type='file' name='inputfile' onChange='getoutput()'><br>
    Output Filename <input id='outputfile' type='text' name='outputfile'><br>
    Extension <input id='extension' type='text' name='extension'>
```

Comment: Sorry to highjack this, but someone deleted my answer to this thread where you said that you had just submitted an app to the App Store and got that UIWebView deprecation warning: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57700996/flutter-how-to-fix-itms-90809-deprecated-api-usage-apple-will-stop-accepting/57705283?noredirect=1#comment101862403_57705283 I'm very curious if Apple will reject it based on the UIWebView usage. Can you please let me know?

Answer (score 53, accepted):

Use [lastIndexOf](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_lastindexof.asp) to get the last `\` as an index and use [substr](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_substr.asp) to get the remaining string starting from the last index of `\`

```js
function getFile(filePath) {
        return filePath.substr(filePath.lastIndexOf('\\') + 1).split('.')[0];
    }

    function getoutput() {
        outputfile.value = getFile(inputfile.value);
        extension.value = inputfile.value.split('.')[1];
    }
```

```html
<input id='inputfile' type='file' name='inputfile' onChange='getoutput()'><br>
    Output Filename <input id='outputfile' type='text' name='outputfile'><br>
    Extension <input id='extension' type='text' name='extension'>
```

**UPDATE**

```js
function getFileNameWithExt(event) {

  if (!event || !event.target || !event.target.files || event.target.files.length === 0) {
    return;
  }

  const name = event.target.files[0].name;
  const lastDot = name.lastIndexOf('.');

  const fileName = name.substring(0, lastDot);
  const ext = name.substring(lastDot + 1);

  outputfile.value = fileName;
  extension.value = ext;
  
}
```

```html
<input id='inputfile' type='file' name='inputfile' onChange='getFileNameWithExt(event)'><br>
  Output Filename <input id='outputfile' type='text' name='outputfile'><br>
  Extension <input id='extension' type='text' name='extension'>
```

Comment: In the output filename box, I only want the filename, not the extension, So, if my input file was example.txt,   "example" should appear in one box and txt in the other.

Comment: It's not true in case file name is 555-1\5476646457441130460313.png

Comment: I cannot access `extension.value` from outside the function.  When I assign it to a variable as `var ext = extension.value`, it stays local no matter what.  How can I fix this?

Comment: you want to return the filename and extension?

Comment: Just the extension.

Comment: @Brian use ```var ext = document.getElementById('extension').value```

Comment: It doesn't work.  Should I put it inside the function or outside the function?

Comment: It works only inside the function.  So still I can't take the value of the variable out.

Comment: Please do something like https://jsbin.com/soyexucehe/edit?html,js,console,output

Comment: Still `var ext` is local.  How can I get `var ext` out of `function getExt()`?

Comment: I don't know what you are trying to do, please share your code also see my answer to your question here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60534853/how-can-i-create-a-javascript-condition-to-display-either-image-preview-of-a-vid/60585923#60585923

Comment: your code does not work if the file name contains a full stop in it

Comment: @BhavinKalal it does. Please check the updated answer.

Answer (score 65):

This is bit old post...just for info

```
   var files = event.target.files
   var filename = files[0].name
   var extension = files[0].type
```

In the type you will find the extension
for eg: if it is jpeg image then,

```
extension = image/jpeg
```

or if pdf then,

```
extension = application/pdf
```

To obtain the exact value, perform extension.replace(/(.*)\//g, '').
you will get the value.

Comment: This is very neat, but comes with a "but"... The `type` property might return empty strings. For example, if you upload a docx file as a client, but don't have MS Word installed on your client machine, then the browser returns an empty string on `type`. Fallback mechanisms are necessary. This behaves differently though in each browser. I've seen this empty string result on `type` with the latest/recent Chrome version and no MS Word installed on my dev machine.

Comment: That regex pattern will only remove the `/`. Should be `extension.replace(/(.*)\//g, '')`

Comment: @Crayons Yes...Thank you

Comment: Incase I upload the *.docx file it returns like this. `application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document` How can I get only extension "docx"?

Answer (score 13):

```
var filePath = $("#inputFile").val(); 
var file_ext = filePath.substr(filePath.lastIndexOf('.')+1,filePath.length);
console.log("File Extension ->-> "+file_ext);
```

It will work if you have dots in filename.

Answer (score 4):

First get the filename, then slice it to various parts.

```
const media_file = event.target.files[0] // event is from the <input> event
const filename = media_file.name

let last_dot = filename.lastIndexOf('.')
let ext = filename.slice(last_dot + 1)
let name = filename.slice(0, last_dot)
```

Answer (score 4):

With less code

```
let fileName = "profile.png";
let extension = fileName.split(".").pop();
```

Answer (score 2):

You could try this out:

```
var fullPath = inputfile.value.split('.')[0];
var filename = fullPath.replace(/^.*[\\\/]/, '');
outputfile.value=filename;`
```

This should remove everything except the filename.

I got it from [How to get the file name from a full path using JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/423376/how-to-get-the-file-name-from-a-full-path-using-javascript).

Answer (score 2):

Simple and quick.

```
   var files = event.target.files[0]
   // for getting only extension 
   var fileExtension = files.type.split("/").pop();
   var fileName = files.name
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is a handy code.

```
    String extension = fileName.substring(fileName.lastIndexOf('.')+1);
    String name = fileName.substring(0, fileName.lastIndexOf('.'));
```

Comment: What language is this?

Comment: Maybe, Java Mix JavaScript

Answer (score 0):

from file[0].type you can get the extension

file[0] looks like 
 File { name: "hcl_icon.ico", lastModified: 1559301004000, webkitRelativePath: "", size: 1150, type: "image/x-icon" }

or by File reader 
 reader.onload = function (e){}
e.target.result gives the src of the file contains Data have extension

Answer (score 0):

I use this to get the filename and the extension

For file name:

```
this.files[0].name.slice(0, this.files[0].name.lastIndexOf("."))
```

For file extension:

```
this.files[0].name.slice(this.files[0].name.lastIndexOf(".") + 1, this.files[0].name.length)
```

Sample code:

```
document.getElementById("file").oninput = function() {
    console.log("File name: "+this.files[0].name.slice(0, this.files[0].name.lastIndexOf(".")))
    console.log("File extension: "+this.files[0].name.slice(this.files[0].name.lastIndexOf(".") + 1, this.files[0].name.length))
}
```

```html
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
</head>
<body>
    <input type="file" id="file">
</body>
<script>
document.getElementById("file").oninput = function(val) {
    console.log("File name: "+this.files[0].name.slice(0, this.files[0].name.lastIndexOf(".")))
    console.log("File extension: "+this.files[0].name.slice(this.files[0].name.lastIndexOf(".") + 1, this.files[0].name.length))
}
</script>
```

Hope this helps